# C++ Convert string (or char*) to wstring (or wchar_t*)

Tags: c++, string, wstring

```
string s = "おはよう";
wstring ws = FUNCTION(s, ws);
```

How would i assign the contents of s to ws?

Searched google and used some techniques but they can't assign the exact content. The content is distorted.

Comment: I don't think `strings` accepts >8-bit characters. Is it already encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: What's your system encoding that it would make `"おはよう"` a system-encoded string?

Comment: I believe MSVC will accept that and make it some multibyte encoding, maybe UTF-8.

Comment: There is no problem with string s = "おはよう"
in debug visual studio, i checked after that assignment s = "おはよう"

But I'm not much familiar with system-encoding thing...how/where to check?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: MSVC doesn't use UTF-8 by default for ANYTHING.  If you enter those characters, it asks which encoding to convert the file to, and defaults to codepage 1252.

Comment: @Samir: more important is what is the encoding of the _file_?  Can you move that string to the beginning of the file and show a hexdump of that part?  We can probably identify it from that.

Answer (score 297):

**NOTE!** See *Note (2023-10-05)* at the bottom!

Assuming that the input string in your example (おはよう) is a UTF-8 encoded (which it isn't, by the looks of it, but let's assume it is for the sake of this explanation :-)) representation of a Unicode string of your interest, then your problem can be fully solved with the standard library (C++11 and newer) alone.

**The TL;DR version:**

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
std::string narrow = converter.to_bytes(wide_utf16_source_string);
std::wstring wide = converter.from_bytes(narrow_utf8_source_string);
```

**Longer online compilable and runnable example:**

(They all show the same example. There are just many for redundancy...)

- http://ideone.com/KA1oty
- http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/5pRLSh
- http://rextester.com/DIJZK52174

**Note (old)**:

As pointed out in the comments and explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17106065/6345 there are cases when using the standard library to convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16 might give unexpected differences in the results on different platforms. For a better conversion, consider `std::codecvt_utf8` as described on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8

**Note (new)**:

Since the `codecvt` header is deprecated in C++17, some worry about the solution presented in this answer were raised. However, the C++ standards committee added an important statement in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0618r0.html saying

> this library component should be retired to Annex D, along side , until a suitable replacement is standardized.

So in the foreseeable future, the `codecvt` solution in this answer is safe and portable.

**Note (2023-10-05)**:

Proposal to remove the deprecated `codecvt` and `wstring_convert` in C++26:

- [Remove Deprecated Unicode Conversion Facets from C++26](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2871r2.pdf)
- [Remove wstring_convert From C++26](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2872r2.pdf)

Comment: Thank you! I do like the explicit references to utf8 and utf16 encodings here. And for using the standard library alone: I wish I could upvote to make this the highest ranking answer all by myself.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to make sure that your inisital string has the right encoding type, you should be using a utf8-encoded string literal to initialize it, like follows: string s = u8"おはよう";

Comment: I dont understand why, but this works..If I Type the character 0x00c3, with is L'Ã' (not sure if you will see it, its an A with a tilde accent) in VS, everything is fine. If I load that character from notepad++ (encoded with utf-8), it loads as 2 chars: 0xc3 and 0x83. Why the hell it comes as 2 chars? So Using the wstring ctor to convert generates 0xffc3 and 0xff83, that shows as 2 japanese like kanjis. Using your method, it converts the 2 chars to 0x00c3 !! =) I have no clue whats happening, but it works..(that stuff is really confuse)

Comment: Check what encoding you save VS files with

Comment: Be aware that this is C++11-only!

Comment: In minGW (gcc/g++ 4.8.1 and -std=c++11 ) the codecvt header does not exist.  Is there an alternative?

Comment: This makes an unportable assumption that wchar_t is 16 bit. The resulting wstring would be very surprising outside Windows.

Comment: @Cubbi - please clarify where that assumption is made, thanks!

Comment: @JohannGerell give it a char string `\xF0\x9F\x8D\x8C` and it will produce two wchar_ts, one holding `0xD83C` and the other holding `0xDF4C`. While it makes some (albeit perverse) sense to put UTF-16 into wstrings on Windows, everyone else would expect a single wchar_t with the value `0x1F34C `. That's what `std::codedvt_utf8` would produce.

Comment: @Cubbi: _"everyone else would expect a single wchar_t with the value 0x1F34C"_ - anyone can see it ()'s a banana ;)

Comment: @Cubbi: So, to be clear, for any readers of this answer and your comment, when you say _"This makes an unportable assumption that wchar_t is 16 bit"_ by _"This"_ you actually mean that the library call `converter.from_bytes` above might return a 2-character `wchar_t` string instead of a 1-character `wchar_t` string, because the library call assumes `wchar_t` is 16 bit on all platforms?

Comment: The library call does what it's supposed to do, produces a utf-16 encoded string and stores it in whatever target type was given (even if it's mismatched, as when this runs on coliru's linux). The assumption is in choosing codecvt_utf8_utf16 instead of codecvt_utf8.

Comment: Added a **Note** section to the answer mentioning the deficiency pointed out by @Cubbi.

Comment: Works on Linux, but after I changed codecvt_utf8_utf16 to codecvt_utf8. Then string -> wstring conversion works just fine!

Comment: May you please provide an example of `std::codecvt_utf8` for beginners

Comment: Please note that `<codecvt>` is deprecated since C++17.

Comment: @tambre - thanks for pointing this out, I added the **Note (new)** paragraph to address this.

Comment: If I were the sole and all powerful ruler of this world, I would decree, that UTF16 is outlawed and only UTF8 and UTF32 are legal and usable without the danger of severe punishment. ;) I mean seriously - what is UTF16 good for if it still is multi-code point?! All this hassle with conversions has the root cause that UTF16 is flawed, IMHO.

Comment: Note that in MSVC, the codecvt_utf8 fails to convert non-BMP codepoints properly, like U+10CFA. Passing an UTF-8 text with such codepoints would not result in proper UTF-16 surrogate pair (like `03 D8 FA DC` for UTF-16-LE), but result in a single UTF-16 unit in the range U+0C80 .. U+0CFF. MultiByteToWideChar is more robust for those cases.

Comment: Thats the theory but its not portable because g++ doesn't implement codecvt unfortunately.  I think it would be easier to get the entire world to only use the expanded latin alphabet for text, tan it would be for the computer science standards and compiler folks to come up with one simple solution to handle wide strings and multibyte encodings.

Comment: "If I were the sole and all powerful ruler of this world..." I'm glad you aren't, just because we have a nauseating surplus of orthodox autocratic leaders already. ;) (OTOH, now that even Microsoft prefers UTF-8 at long last, UTF-16 is fading into oblivion, and that's OK. It still does have some valid use cases, in certain well-defined problem spaces with a closed set of text inputs, I guess. I wouldn't punish those working in those niches, that's enough punishment for them already, I suppose. :) )

Comment: @Sz. A number of widely used file system use UTF-16. Also backward compatibility, you'd make a great amount of documentation and data insccessible by phasing out utf-16 (utf-8 clearly not enough to represent international tect)

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: "utf-8 clearly not enough to represent international tect" - what do you mean?

Comment: @JohannGerell its main focus is representation. It's more efficient for representing or inspecting long texts or large amount of data than UTF-8. Yeah, big computer systems are now powerful enough, be we have classes of small scale and realtime platforms encrouching into everyday applications.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: " *its* main focus is representation" - what is "*its*" in that claim? I asked about your claim that "utf-8 clearly not enough to represent international tect", so I wonder what *its* is in your new claim. Sorry, can't really follow what you mean

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I think you meant to reply to BitTickler's comment, and misunderstood mine, as I agree with your point ("...widely used file systems use UTF-16. Also backward compatibility..."), and that's exactly why I said that "[UTF-16] still does have some valid use cases", and "I wouldn't punish those".

Answer (score 63):

```
int StringToWString(std::wstring &ws, const std::string &s)
{
    std::wstring wsTmp(s.begin(), s.end());

    ws = wsTmp;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting constructor. Also note that it can be used to convert wstring to string in the same way.

Comment: This only works if all the characters are single byte, i.e. ASCII or [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1). Anything multi-byte will fail miserably, including UTF-8. The question clearly contains multi-byte characters.

Comment: This answer is clearly insufficient and does nothing but copy narrow characters as is into wide characters. See the other answers, particularly the one by Johann Gerell, for how to properly go from a multi-byte or utf8 encoded string to a utf16 wstring.

Comment: this answer is dangerous and will probably break on non-ascii system. i.e. an arabic filename will get mangled by this hack.

Comment: unfortunately mingw doesn't have the header to do it the 'right' way so only this 'incorrect' way is possible. :(

Comment: @BrianJack: The more correct way to do it then is to use a 3rd party lib or function.

Comment: This answer is useful if you ignore the nuance of the question's body and focus on the question title, which is what brought me here from Google.  As is, the question's title is *extremely* misleading and should be altered to reflect the true question being asked

Comment: This answer is wrong for many reasons. As pointed out by others, this will work for a very limited subset of character encodings in the source string. The character encoding used by the question is not part of that subset. It's also completely unclear to me, why this function returns a useless integer value in place of constructed wide character string. Plus, throwing code at the reader without providing an explanation on what it does and why it works is not very useful.

Comment: This works only for 7-bit ASCII characters. For latin1, it works only if char is configured as unsigned. If the type char is signed (which is most of time the case), characters > 127 will give wrong results.

Comment: If you want *this kind of* conversion to work **reliably**, do `std::wstring c(const std::string& i){size_t n =i.length();std::wstring o;o.reserve(n);for(size_t p=0;p<n;++p)o.push_back(i[p]&255);return o;}` − the trick is the `&255`.

Answer (score 42):

Your question is underspecified. Strictly, that example is a syntax error. However, [`std::mbstowcs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbstowcs) is probably what you're looking for.

It is a C-library function and operates on buffers, but here's an easy-to-use idiom, courtesy of Mooing Duck:

```
std::wstring ws(s.size(), L' '); // Overestimate number of code points.
ws.resize(std::mbstowcs(&ws[0], s.c_str(), s.size())); // Shrink to fit.
```

Comment: string s = "おはよう";
wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[ s.size() ];
size_t num_chars = mbstowcs( buf, s.c_str(), s.size() );
wstring ws( buf, num_chars );
// ws = distorted

Comment: @Samir: You have to make sure the runtime encoding is the same as the compile-time encoding. You might need to `setlocale` or adjust compiler flags. I don't know because I don't use Windows, but this is why it's not a common feature. Consider the other answer if possible.

Comment: `std::string ws(s.size()); ws.resize(mbstowcs(&ws[0], s.c_str(), s.size());` RAII FTW

Comment: Also... it wouldn't compile for me as is: I had to make it "std::wstring ws(s.size(), 0);" to get it to compile with Visual Studio 2012. In the end, I opted to go with Johann Gerell's answer using "std::codecvt_utf8_utf16" anyhow. Thanks.

Comment: @DLRdave OK. This is an interesting page. It's been getting high traffic consistently for years and the answers reflect different time periods. Support for those `std::codecvt_*_*` classes is fairly new; they didn't exist when I wrote this and I haven't yet verified that they work in GCC. The highest voted answer is clearly incorrect so at least you didn't go that way :v) .

Comment: Writing over the wstring's internal buffer (accessed via &ws[0] above) potentially may break the string interface by relying on a contiguous implementation. For example see this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1043318/406859

Comment: @WaffleSouffle That's out of date. Contiguous implementations have been required since 2011 and implementations quit such tricks long before that.

Comment: and some environments like mingw still don't have the codecvt header so some of the 'better' solutions earlier up don't work meaning this problem still has no good solutions in mingw even as of Dec 2014

Comment: @Potatoswatter `error C4996: 'mbstowcs': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using mbstowcs_s instead.` Maybe you should update something?

Comment: @Simple The `_s` or safe family of functions take an extra size parameter. Updated.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I included the `stdlib.h` but it tells me: `namespace "std" has no member "mbstowcs_s"` why?

Comment: @Simple Well that’s sad. C++ hasn’t gotten around to adopting the newer C function even as the old one generates warnings. I updated the answer again.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Shouldn't you delete your answer then? I mean your initial answer was C++ but the compiler error forced you to update it but then it turned to be a C answer however the question is C++.

Comment: @Simple There’s nothing wrong with calling `mbstowcs_s` from C++, and this shows how to use it properly with standard strings.

Comment: @Simple: The function `mbstowcs` can be hard to use safely, but the way it was used in this answer ("overestimate number of code points") is perfectly safe. Microsoft decided to aggressively discourage people from using such functions (Visual Studio treats them as errors by default). But as their [documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/security-features-in-the-crt?view=msvc-170), they aren't planning to remove the functions – they are just recommending not to use them. [...]

Comment: Unfortunately, in many cases the secure alternatives are not widely supported yet. My suggestions are: understand and be aware of the dangers; try to use the more secure versions if possible; or else disable Microsoft's warnings by inserting `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` at the top of the file before the #include's, or by compiling with `/D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`.

Comment: Check that the return value of `mbstowcs` isn't `(size_t)-1` before passing it to `ws.resize`.

Answer (score 26):

If you are using *Windows*/*Visual Studio* and need to convert a string to wstring you could use:

```
#include <AtlBase.h>
#include <atlconv.h>
...
string s = "some string";
CA2W ca2w(s.c_str());
wstring w = ca2w;
printf("%s = %ls", s.c_str(), w.c_str());
```

Same procedure for converting a wstring to string (sometimes you will need to specify a *codepage*):

```
#include <AtlBase.h>
#include <atlconv.h>
...
wstring w = L"some wstring";
CW2A cw2a(w.c_str());
string s = cw2a;
printf("%s = %ls", s.c_str(), w.c_str());
```

You could specify a *codepage* and even UTF8 (that's pretty nice when working with *JNI*/*Java*). A *standard* way of [converting a std::wstring to utf8 std::string is showed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12903901/2692914).

```
// 
// using ATL
CA2W ca2w(str, CP_UTF8);

// 
// or the standard way taken from the answer above
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

// convert UTF-8 string to wstring
std::wstring utf8_to_wstring (const std::string& str) {
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;
    return myconv.from_bytes(str);
}

// convert wstring to UTF-8 string
std::string wstring_to_utf8 (const std::wstring& str) {
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;
    return myconv.to_bytes(str);
}
```

If you want to know more about *codepages* there is an interesting article on Joel on Software: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

These CA2W (Convert Ansi to Wide=unicode) macros are part of [ATL and MFC String Conversion Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx), samples included.

Sometimes you will need to disable the security warning #4995', I don't know of other workaround (to me it happen when I compiled for WindowsXp in VS2012).

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4995)
#include <AtlBase.h>
#include <atlconv.h>
#pragma warning(pop)
```

**Edit:**
Well, according to [this article](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) the article by Joel appears to be: "while entertaining, it is pretty light on actual technical details". Article: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encoding And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: Probably the fact that it promotes non-portable code.

Comment: Yes, that's why I stated that this works only in Windows/Visual Studio. But at least this solution is correct, and not this one: `char* str = "hello worlddd"; wstring wstr (str, str+strlen(str));`

Comment: Additional note: CA2W is under namespace of ATL.  (ATL::CA2W)

Answer (score 24):

Windows API only, pre C++11 implementation, in case someone needs it:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

using std::runtime_error;
using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::wstring;

wstring utf8toUtf16(const string & str)
{
   if (str.empty())
      return wstring();

   size_t charsNeeded = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, 
      str.data(), (int)str.size(), NULL, 0);
   if (charsNeeded == 0)
      throw runtime_error("Failed converting UTF-8 string to UTF-16");

   vector<wchar_t> buffer(charsNeeded);
   int charsConverted = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, 
      str.data(), (int)str.size(), &buffer[0], buffer.size());
   if (charsConverted == 0)
      throw runtime_error("Failed converting UTF-8 string to UTF-16");

   return wstring(&buffer[0], charsConverted);
}
```

Comment: You can optimize it. There's no need to do double copy of the string by using a `vector`. Simply reserve the characters in the string by doing `wstring strW(charsNeeded + 1);` and then use it as buffer for conversion: `&strW[0]`. Lastly ensure last null is present after conversion by doing `strW[charsNeeded] = 0;`

Comment: @c00000fd, as far as I know, the std::basic_string internal buffer is required to be continuous only since C++11 standard. My code is pre C++11, as noted on the top of the post. Therefore, the &strW[0] code would be not standard compliant and might legitimately crash at runtime.

Answer (score 24):

Here's a way to combining `string`, `wstring` and mixed string constants to `wstring`. Use the `wstringstream` class.

This does NOT work for multi-byte character encodings. This is just a dumb way of throwing away type safety and expanding 7 bit characters from std::string into the lower 7 bits of each character of std:wstring. This is only useful if you have a 7-bit ASCII strings and you need to call an API that requires wide strings.

```
#include <sstream>

std::string narrow = "narrow";
std::wstring wide = L"wide";

std::wstringstream cls;
cls << " abc " << narrow.c_str() << L" def " << wide.c_str();
std::wstring total= cls.str();
```

Comment: The answer seems interesting. Could you please explain a bit: will this work for multi-byte encodings, and why/how?

Comment: encoding schemes are orthogonal to the storage class. `string` stores 1 byte characters and `wstring` stores 2 byte characters. something like utf8 stores mulitbyte characters as a series of 1 byte values, i.e. in a `string`.  the string classes don't help with encoding. I'm not an expert on encoding classes in c++.

Comment: Any reason why this one is not the best answer, given how short and simple it is?  Any cases that it does not cover?

Comment: @MarkLakata, I read your answer to the first comment but am still not sure. Will it work for multi-byte characters? In other words, is it not prone to the same pitfall as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8969776/3258851)?

Comment: @Marc.2377 This does NOT work for multi-byte character encodings. This is just a dumb way of throwing away type safety and expanding 7 bit characters from `std::string` into the lower 7 bits of each character of `std:wstring`.  This is only useful if you have a 7-bit ASCII strings and you need to call an API that requires wide strings.  Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8969776/3258851 if you need something more sophisticated.

Comment: @MarkLakata, interestingly, I just tested both your answer and the one you linked to. Your answer does work, the other one does not. I used `"おはよう"` as a test string.

Answer (score 20):

From `char*` to `wstring`:

```
char* str = "hello worlddd";
wstring wstr (str, str+strlen(str));
```

From `string` to `wstring`:

```
string str = "hello worlddd";
wstring wstr (str.begin(), str.end());
```

Note this only works well if the string being converted contains only ASCII characters.

Comment: Because this only works if the encoding is Windows-1252, which can't even hold the letters in the question.

Comment: this is least error prone way of doing it, when you know you dealing with ASCII. Which is a prominent usecase when porting apps to newer api's.

Comment: This is **not** the way. If you are using Visual Studio you should use `atlconv.h`. Check the other answers.

Comment: Points for simplicity!

Answer (score 12):

This variant of it is my favourite in real life. It converts the input, **if it is valid** UTF-8, to the respective `wstring`. If the input is corrupted, the `wstring` is constructed out of the single bytes. This is extremely helpful if you cannot really be sure about the quality of your input data.

```
std::wstring convert(const std::string& input)
{
    try
    {
        std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
        return converter.from_bytes(input);
    }
    catch(std::range_error& e)
    {
        size_t length = input.length();
        std::wstring result;
        result.reserve(length);
        for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            result.push_back(input[i] & 0xFF);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just launched this question based on your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669048/c-converting-to-a-wstring-why-would-a-character-be-anded-to-a-byte#49669048 can you kindly take a look

Answer (score 9):

using Boost.Locale:

```
ws = boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<wchar_t>(s);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use boost path or std path; which is a lot more easier.
boost path  is easier for cross-platform application

```
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

//s to w
std::string s = "xxx";
auto w = fs::path(s).wstring();

//w to s
std::wstring w = L"xxx";
auto s = fs::path(w).string();
```

if you like to use std:

```
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

//The same
```

c++ older version

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

//The same
```

The code within still implement a converter which you dont have to unravel the detail.

Answer (score 6):

For me the most uncomplicated option without big overhead is:

Include:

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlconv.h>
```

Convert:

```
char* whatever = "test1234";
std::wstring lwhatever = std::wstring(CA2W(std::string(whatever).c_str()));
```

If needed:

```
lwhatever.c_str();
```

Answer (score 4):

String to wstring

```
std::wstring Str2Wstr(const std::string& str)
{
    int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), NULL, 0);
    std::wstring wstrTo(size_needed, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &wstrTo[0], size_needed);
    return wstrTo;
}
```

wstring to String

```
std::string Wstr2Str(const std::wstring& wstr)
{
    typedef std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> convert_typeX;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_typeX, wchar_t> converterX;
    return converterX.to_bytes(wstr);
}
```

Comment: This Str2Wstr has a problem with 0 termination. It is not possible to concatenate the generated wstrings anymore via "+" (like in wstring s3 = s1 + s2). I will post a answer soon solving this problem. Have to do some testing for memory leaks first.

Answer (score 4):

If you have QT and if you are lazy to implement a function and stuff you can use

```
std::string str;
QString(str).toStdWString()
```

Comment: Almost, but you should just start out with a `QString`, because the `QString` constructor can't accept a string for some reason.

Comment: You can use https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromStdString

Comment: This is nice. Also, you can use *.c_str()* to let QString accept your string in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my super basic solution that might not work for everyone. But would work for a lot of people.

It requires usage of the Guideline Support Library.
Which is a pretty official C++ library that was designed by many C++ committee authors:

- https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines
- https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL

```
    std::string to_string(std::wstring const & wStr)
    {
        std::string temp = {};

        for (wchar_t const & wCh : wStr)
        {
            // If the string can't be converted gsl::narrow will throw
            temp.push_back(gsl::narrow<char>(wCh));
        }

        return temp;
    }
```

All my function does is allow the conversion if possible. Otherwise throw an exception.

Via the usage of gsl::narrow (https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es49-if-you-must-use-a-cast-use-a-named-cast)

Answer (score 1):

method s2ws works well. Hope helps.

```
std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& s) {
    std::string curLocale = setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); 
    const char* _Source = s.c_str();
    size_t _Dsize = mbstowcs(NULL, _Source, 0) + 1;
    wchar_t *_Dest = new wchar_t[_Dsize];
    wmemset(_Dest, 0, _Dsize);
    mbstowcs(_Dest,_Source,_Dsize);
    std::wstring result = _Dest;
    delete []_Dest;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, curLocale.c_str());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is with all of these answers allocating dynamic memory in an unsafe way, and then copying the data from the buffer to the string?  Why does nobody get rid of the unsafe middleman?

Comment: hahakubile, can you help please with something similar for ws2s ?

Answer (score 1):

Based upon my own testing (On windows 8, vs2010) mbstowcs can actually damage original string, it works only with ANSI code page. If MultiByteToWideChar/WideCharToMultiByte can also cause string corruption - but they tends to replace characters which they don't know with '?' question marks, but mbstowcs tends to stop when it encounters unknown character and cut string at that very point. (I have tested Vietnamese characters on finnish windows).

So prefer Multi*-windows api function over analogue ansi C functions.

Also what I've noticed shortest way to encode string from one codepage to another is not use MultiByteToWideChar/WideCharToMultiByte api function calls but their analogue ATL macros: W2A / A2W.

So analogue function as mentioned above would sounds like:

```
wstring utf8toUtf16(const string & str)
{
   USES_CONVERSION;
   _acp = CP_UTF8;
   return A2W( str.c_str() );
}
```

_acp is declared in USES_CONVERSION macro.

Or also function which I often miss when performing old data conversion to new one:

```
string ansi2utf8( const string& s )
{
   USES_CONVERSION;
   _acp = CP_ACP;
   wchar_t* pw = A2W( s.c_str() );

   _acp = CP_UTF8;
   return W2A( pw );
}
```

But please notice that those macro's use heavily stack - don't use for loops or recursive loops for same function - after using W2A or A2W macro - better to return ASAP, so stack will be freed from temporary conversion.

Answer (score 1):

### utf-8 implementation

Assuming that your `std::string` is utf8-encoded, this is a platform-independent implementation of wstring-string conversion functions:

```cpp
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

std::string wstring_to_utf8(std::wstring const& str)
{
  std::wstring_convert<std::conditional<
        sizeof(wchar_t) == 4,
        std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>,
        std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>>::type> converter;
  return converter.to_bytes(str);
}

std::wstring utf8_to_wstring(std::string const& str)
{
  std::wstring_convert<std::conditional<
        sizeof(wchar_t) == 4,
        std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>,
        std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>>::type> converter;
  return converter.from_bytes(str);
}
```

The currently most upvoted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18597384/758345) looks similar, but produces incorrect results for non-BMP characters (i.e. Emojis ) on non-Windows platforms. `wchar_t` is UTF-16 on windows, but UTF-32 everywhere else. The `std::conditional` takes care of that distinction.

### MSVC Deprecation Warning

On msvc this might generate some deprecation warnings. You can disable these by wrapping the functions in

```cpp
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
<the two functions>
#pragma warning(pop)
```

[Johann Gerell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18597384/758345) explains why it's ok to disable that warning.

### Getting utf-8 on msvc

Note that when you write a normal string in your source (like `std::string s = "おはよう";`), it won't be utf-8 encoded per default on msvc. I would strongly recommend setting your msvc character set to utf-8 to address this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 0):

`std::string -> wchar_t[]` with safe `mbstowcs_s` function:

```
auto ws = std::make_unique<wchar_t[]>(s.size() + 1);
mbstowcs_s(nullptr, ws.get(), s.size() + 1, s.c_str(), s.size());
```

This is from my sample [code](https://github.com/vSzemkel/GCC/blob/b35de68c1cea2eb97549f333510545e412b5ef6b/currency_rate_avarege.cpp#L75)

Answer (score -1):

use this code to convert your string to wstring

```
std::wstring string2wString(const std::string& s){
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0); 
    wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
    std::wstring r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}

int main(){
    std::wstring str="your string";
    std::wstring wStr=string2wString(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that the question has no mentioning of Windows and this answer is Windows-only.

Comment: `CP_ACP` is most certainly the wrong argument. All of a sudden, the executing thread's environment state has an effect on the behavior of the code. Not advisable. Specify a fixed character encoding in your conversion. (And consider handling errors.)

Answer (score -3):

`string s = "おはよう";` is an error.

You should use wstring directly:

```
wstring ws = L"おはよう";
```

Comment: That's not going to work either. You'll have to convert those non-BMP characters to C escape sequences.

Comment: @Dave: it does work if your compiler supports unicode in source files, and all the ones in the last decade do (visual studio, gcc, ...)

Comment: Hi, regardless of the default system encoding (I may have Arabic as my default system encoding for example), what should the encoding of the source code file for L"おはよう" to work? should it be in UTF-16, or can I have UTF-8 without BOM for the .cpp file encoding?

Comment: @afriza: it doesn't really matter as long as your compile supports it

Comment: It is not an error; extended characters in a "narrow" string are defined to map to multibyte sequences. The compiler should support it as long as the OS does, which is the least you can ask.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde Those Japanese Hiragana's are in BMP.