# How to convert a TCHAR array to std::string?

Tags: c++, string, windows, unicode, tchar

How do I convert a `TCHAR` array to `std::string` (not to `std::basic_string`)?

Comment: You realize std::string is just a typedef for a std::basic_string<char>?

Comment: And do you want to convert a specifically Unicode or MBCS TCHAR (i.e. really WCHAR or CHAR) into a std::string (i.e. char) always, or convert CHAR to string and WCHAR to wstring, or something else?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`TCHAR` is just a typedef that, depending on your compilation configuration, either defaults to `char` or `wchar_t`.

Standard Template Library supports both ASCII (with `std::string`) and wide character sets (with `std::wstring`). All you need to do is to *typedef* String as either std::string or std::wstring depending on your compilation configuration. To maintain flexibility you can use the following code:

```
#ifndef UNICODE  
  typedef std::string String; 
#else
  typedef std::wstring String; 
#endif
```

Now you may use `String` in your code and let the compiler handle the nasty parts. String will now have constructors that lets you convert `TCHAR` to `std::string` or `std::wstring`.

Comment: problem is I have to call a interface which accepts std::string so i cant send std::wstring :(

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804298/c-how-to-convert-wstring-into-string/4804506#4804506) for how to convert from wstring to string.

Comment: @ebyrob: The same thing Alok Save did with std::string and std::wstring you'd also have to do with std::cout and std::wcout.

Comment: @antred so `typedef std::wcout std_tcout` and `std_tstring` etc?  I can't... get myself to facade a standard like that.  Then again, I used to do it for graphics operations all the time.  Why not `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` for the first half of the typedef of string is there a discernible difference?

Comment: @ashmish2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573834/c-convert-string-or-char-to-wstring-or-wchar-t shows conversion between `std::wstring` and `std::string`, assuming UTF-8, but there are other scenarios.  Considering this is VS, I'd just try to stick to `W2A()` and `A2W()` in most cases though.

Answer (score 7):

My answer is late, I'll admit that, but with the answers of 'Alok Save' and some research I've found a good way! (Note: I didn't test this version a lot, so it might not work in every case, but from what I tested it should):

```
TCHAR t = SomeFunctionReturningTCHAR();
std::string str;

#ifndef UNICODE
    str = t;
#else
    std::wstring wStr = t;
    str = std::string(wStr.begin(), wStr.end());
#endif

std::cout << str << std::endl; //<-- should work!
```

Comment: It works only for 7-bit ASCII, but prints garbage for other characters.

Answer (score 5):

TCHAR type is `char` or `wchar_t`, depending on your project settings.

```
 #ifdef UNICODE
     // TCHAR type is wchar_t
 #else
     // TCHAR type is char
 #endif
```

So if you must use `std::string` instead of `std::wstring`, you should use a converter function. I may use [`wcstombs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d7tc9zw%28VS.80%29.aspx) or [`WideCharToMultiByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
TCHAR * text;

#ifdef UNICODE
    /*/
    // Simple C
    const size_t size = ( wcslen(text) + 1 ) * sizeof(wchar_t);
    wcstombs(&buffer[0], text, size);
    std::vector<char> buffer(size);
    /*/
    // Windows API (I would use this)
    std::vector<char> buffer;
    int size = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, text, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (size > 0) {
        buffer.resize(size);
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, text, -1, static_cast<BYTE*>(&buffer[0]), buffer.size(), NULL, NULL);
    }
    else {
        // Error handling
    }
    //*/
    std::string string(&buffer[0]);
#else
    std::string string(text);
#endif
```

Comment: I tried it, got:   error C2664: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::basic_string(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TCHAR [50]' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &'

Comment: @user396483: I just tried it in VS2012. Code: [link](http://store.naszta.hu/main/example01.cpp).

Answer (score 5):

TCHAR is either char or wchar_t, so a

```
typedef basic_string<TCHAR>   tstring;
```

is one way of doing it.

The other is to skip `char` altogether and just use `std::wstring`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple!

```
std::string tcharToChar(TCHAR* buffer)
{
    char *charBuffer = NULL;
    std::string returnValue;
    int lengthOfbuffer = lstrlenW(buffer);
    if(buffer!=NULL)
    {
        charBuffer = (char*)calloc(lengthOfbuffer+1,sizeof(char));
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    for (int index = 0;
        index < lengthOfbuffer;
        index++)
    {
        char *singleCharacter = (char*)calloc(2,sizeof(char));
        singleCharacter[0] = (char)buffer[index];
        singleCharacter[1] = '\0';
        strcat(charBuffer, singleCharacter);
        free(singleCharacter );
    }
    strcat(charBuffer, "\0");
    returnValue.append(charBuffer);
    free(charBuffer);
    return returnValue;
    
}
```

Comment: Now you have an owning raw pointer you need to clean up. Why not return a `std::string` instead? Edit : You also leak a ton of tiny buffers with `singleCharacter`. This solution is not acceptable as-is. There is no need to dynamically allocate for `singleCharacter` and I don't see the need for `strcat` to write a string character-by-character.

Comment: i accept it was a lazy solution. i have corrected the leaks and returned a std::string. Thanks for your input.

Comment: With the changes the answer isn't strictly harmful, so I removed my downvote. But it is still not a very good solution. There is no need for `strcat` or `singleCharacter`, you can just push the last character to the position `index` of `charBuffer`. You also don't need to allocate for `charBufffer` because `std::string` already has a character buffer you can use. Manual memory management has fallen heavily out of favor in modern C++ and should generally not be part of recommended solutions unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: `calloc`, `malloc`, etc. are C memory allocation functions and are not as easy to use in C++. They do not start the lifetime of objects. `new` should be used instead, but even then `new` is also discouraged. `std::vector` and `std::make_unique` should replace the vast majority of manual memory management.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution :

```
TCHAR str[256] = {};

// put something in str...


// convert to string
std::string strtmp(&str[0], &str[255]);

std::cout << strtmp << std::endl;
```

Comment: This will cause unexpected behaviour if the original string contains any non-ascii characters

Comment: I believe this will always produce an `std::string` with a length of 255 characters, even when the string contains a null terminator. `std::string` can contain nulls, specifically if you use the range based constructor like in this case.