# Can't pass argv into a string in one project; Works fine in another

Tags: c++, string, winapi, argv, tchar

I have two c++ win32 console application project. Both have exactly identical code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3){

        cout << "Program needs 2 arguments";
    }
    else{
        string filePath = argv[1];
        string flag = argv[2];
        unsigned long int size;
        bool najden = false;

        //odpri datoteko
        ifstream idatoteka(filePath, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
        if (idatoteka){
            if (flag != "-c" && flag != "-e"){
                cout << "unknown flag";
            }
            else{
                if (flag == "-c"){
                    //kompresija
                }
                else{
                    //dekompresija
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            cout << "This file doesn't exist\n";
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The silly thing is that one of them is giving me an error where I try to pass argv[1] and argv[2] into string variables. The error message is as follows:

```
cannot convert from '_TCHAR *' to 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'
```

Since when doesn't this work and how can one of two identical projects possibly generate an error?

Comment: You can find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291458/how-to-convert-tchar-array-to-stdstring)

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved. But how does the compiler decide when it's going to use wstring and when it's going to use string? The code is identical. Also, can I make it use wstring by default (without having to always type wstring)?

Comment: I found a final solution by comparing the Project properties after learning about string and wstring. The solution is to have the character set set to "Use multi-byte character set". Then the compiler will let you pass from _TCHAR* to string.

Comment: @user1956373 Note that this technique (using things like _TCHAR, _tmain, etc.) must be classified as an experiment that failed.  The way you process a `std::wstring` is (normally) significantly different than what you do with a `std::string`; you have to write different code for each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_TCHAR` is either defined as `wchar_t` or `char` depending on whether the project is set to compile for Unicode or not.  When you have a project being compiled for Ansi/MBCS, `_TCHAR*` (ie `char*`) can be assigned to `std::string`.  When you have a project being compiled for Unicode instead, `_TCHAR*` (ie `wchar_t*`) cannot be assigned to `std::string`, you have to use `std::wstring` instead, or convert the Unicode data to Ansi/MBCS at runtime.

If you really want the same code to compile in both configurations, you will have to use `std::basic_string<_TCHAR>` and `std::basic_ifstream<_TCHAR>`, wrap literals in `_T()`, etc.  For example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3){
        cout << "Program needs 2 arguments";
    }
    else{
        basic_string<_TCHAR> filePath = argv[1];
        basic_string<_TCHAR> flag = argv[2];
        unsigned long int size;
        bool najden = false;

        //odpri datoteko
        basic_ifstream<_TCHAR> idatoteka(filePath, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
        if (idatoteka){
            if (flag != _T("-c") && flag != _T("-e")){
                cout << "unknown flag";
            }
            else{
                if (flag == _T("-c")){
                    //kompresija
                }
                else{
                    //dekompresija
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            cout << "This file doesn't exist\n";
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Windows has been a Unicode OS for a LONG LONG time.  Using `_TCHAR` only makes sense if you are developing for Windows 9x/ME.  Otherwise, you really should be using Unicode only and not `_TCHAR` at all:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int wmain(int argc, WCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3){
        wcout << L"Program needs 2 arguments";
    }
    else{
        wstring filePath = argv[1];
        wstring flag = argv[2];
        unsigned long int size;
        bool najden = false;

        //odpri datoteko
        wifstream idatoteka(filePath, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
        if (idatoteka){
            if (flag != L"-c" && flag != L"-e"){
                wcout << L"unknown flag";
            }
            else{
                if (flag == L"-c"){
                    //kompresija
                }
                else{
                    //dekompresija
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            wcout << L"This file doesn't exist\n";
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```