# Cannot convert from 'TCHAR [260]' to 'std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>

Tags: c++, char, tchar

> error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'TCHAR [260]' to
>   'std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>

I get this error, been stuck on this for a few hours..

```
TCHAR szModName[MAX_PATH];
if (!GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, hMods[i], szModName, sizeof(szModName) / sizeof(TCHAR))) // Get the full path to the module's file
    continue;

wstring modName = szModName; <-------- this is what im having problem with
```

Comment: At least you didn't apply an erroneous C-style cast to get rid of the error, like so many seem to do (and then wonder why their program crashes or their strings look weird).  I give kudos to that.

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291458/how-to-convert-a-tchar-array-to-stdstring ?

Answer (score 2):

`TCHAR` is defined as either `char` or `wchar_t` depending on whether you have the `UNICODE` macro defined. In your case, it looks like it is not defined, so you are trying to construct a `std::wstring` from a `char[]` array.

I would advise you to *always* use wide APIs on Windows, because that is the only way to get proper Unicode support on there:

```
wchar_t szModName[MAX_PATH];
if (!GetModuleFileNameExW(hProcess, hMods[i], szModName, MAX_PATH))
    continue;

wstring modName = szModName;
```

`GetModuleFileNameEx` is not a function, but rather is a macro that expands to either `GetModuleFileNameExA` or `GetModuleFileNameExW` depending on the `UNICODE` macro.

Originally, the `TCHAR` variants were provided to ease transition from old Windows versions without Unicode support to newer NT-based Windows versions with Unicode support.  Nowadays, there is no reason to use the ANSI variants at all.

Comment: Alternatively, you can do away with the temp buffer and receive the filename into the `std::wstring` directly, eg: `wstring modName(MAX_PATH, 0); DWORD len = GetModuleFileNameExW(hProcess, hMods[i], &modName[0] /* or: modName.data() */, MAX_PATH); if (!len) continue; modName.resize(len);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau `data()` returns `const wchar_t *` before C++17, so `&modName[0]` might be better for now.

Comment: that is why i put `data()` in comments