# Getting build error while assigning (converting) a TCHAr array to a std::string object

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am using unicode character set(Generic requirement is too use unicode only). 
I wnat to somehow place the contents of TCHAr array into a std::string obj, so that I can use the functions of this obj. 
My code snippet is as follows:

```
TCHAR arr[256];
std::wstring w_str;
std::string s_str;

w_str(arr);  ---> Error 1
s_str(w_str.begin,w_str.end);  ---> Error 2.
```

> Error 1 :    I am gettin the error C2064: "Term does not evaluate to a
>   function taking 1 parameter.
>
> Error 2:      I am gettin the error C2064: "Term does not evaluate to
>   a function taking 2 parameter.

**Can anyone kindly help me in this; let me know how to assign contents of a TCHAR (using unicode char set), to a string object.**

Comment: I`m assuming you are looking for `w_str = arr;`, but there are other problems with your code also.

Comment: Yes somehow I want to convert tchar[256] array into  a string object (wstring or string), so that I will be able to use the functions like substr() etc.. in wstring or string.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the string objects as function (i.e. invoking `operator()`), but `std::basic_string` (from which `std::string` and `std::wstring` is typedefed) doesn't have that operator. Instead you should do the initialization when constructing the strings:

```
std::wstring w_str(arr);
std::string s_str(w_str.begin(), w_str.end());
```

However, I think you will still get an error with the last construction, because `std::string` and `std::wstring` uses different character types.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're trying to call the constructor for `std::wstring` and `std::string`, but you're doing it the wrong way. Instead, initialize the objects at the time of declaration:

```
TCHAR arr[256];
std::wstring w_str(arr);
std::string s_str(w_str.begin(), w_str.end());
```

That's not going to solve all of your problems, though. You can't convert directly from a Unicode (wide) string to a narrow string. You're going to have to do some sort of conversion. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804298/c-how-to-convert-wstring-into-string) for possible solutions.

It's strange to require this at all, though. Pick a string type and stick with it. If you're programming Windows and therefore using Unicode strings, you want to use `std::wstring` throughout.

Comment: The problem in declaring as above is that, w_str is a global variable which would get populated inside a function & TCHAR arr[256] is a local array variable inside this function.  SO HOW CAN I INITIALIZE w_str(arr) WITH arr. ?