# Easiest way to convert UnicodeString to const char* in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, api, unicode-string, c++builder-xe2

I'm new in c++ and have problem with converting UnicodeString to string, so now searching for easiest method to convert from one type to other.

I want to use basic windows function which needs string with UnicodeString, how to make code work?

```
UnicodeString Exec = "notepad";
WinExec(Exec.c_str(), 0);
```

Environment used is c++ builder xe2

Comment: [`WideCharToMultiByte()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) is probably what you're looking for. Read carefully. It is fairly straight-forward.

Comment: `wstring_convert` isn't bad ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `std::string` can not store unicode data. You will need a std::wstring for that.

I've never heard of UnicodeString before, but looking at the API here:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.UnicodeString_Methods

It has a function called .c_str() which returns a wchar_t* which you can then use to construct a [std::wstring](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/)

If you really need a std::string, then have a look at this answer.

[How to convert wstring into string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804298/how-to-convert-wstring-into-string)

Comment: [wchar_t is not Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character#C.2FC.2B.2B) and you can't rely on `std::wstring` being big enough to store a Unicode character. If at all possible use `std::u16string` or `std::u32string` as appropriate.

Comment: Yes, apologies, wchar_t `may` store unicode characters but it's size is compiler dependent. Thanks @Captain Obvlious

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for complete unicode support in C++ go for ICU API. Here is the website where you can find everything about it. http://site.icu-project.org/