# cannot convert FindFileData.cFileName to string

Tags: c++, winapi

I am making great headways but I have 2 problems that have been slowing me down for days. The biggest is that I want to save `FindFileData.cFileName` as string but I cannot ! Any help ?

Comment: Post some code! What did you try?

Comment: I usually do but this time I searched on the net for possible solutions, I wrote some attempts but they looked like garbage so i deleted everything and asked the question here.

Answer (score 2):

I copied this from here: [How to convert wstring into string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804298/how-to-convert-wstring-into-string/4804506#4804506)
It converts wstring directly to string ( including FindFileData.cFileName). Any better suggestion or any useful comment ?

```
#include <clocale>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

inline std::string narrow(std::wstring const& text)
{
    std::locale const loc("");
    wchar_t const* from = text.c_str();
    std::size_t const len = text.size();
    std::vector<char> buffer(len + 1);
    std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t> >(loc).narrow(from, from + len, '_', &buffer[0]);
    return std::string(&buffer[0], &buffer[len]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [`WIN32_FIND_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference page `cFileName` is of type [`TCHAR[]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#TCHAR). If UNICODE is enabled (`TCHAR` is `wchar_t`) use `std::wstring`:

```
#include <string>
std::wstring ws(FindFileData.cFileName);
```

otherwise use `std::string` (as `TCHAR` is `char`):

```
std::string ws(FindFileData.cFileName);
```

Or, to cater for both:

```
std::basic_string<TCHAR> s(FindFileData.cFileName);
// std::string is a typedef for std::basic_string<char>
// std::wstring is a typedef for std::basic_string<wchar_t>
```

Comment: I got to this point, I know how to do it ..... but then how to convert wstring to string ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that. Use a `wstring`.

Comment: because I always want to learn more than what I currently know ! :-)

Comment: `string s(ws.begin(), ws.end());`