# qt how do i convert cFilename to QString type

Tags: c++, qt

I have a path stored in cFilename object, and Iam trying to create a QSound Object, but while constructing the object I have give the path name as argument or during using play function i have to give the path name, and QSound takes only of type QString. How do I convert the cFilename object to of type QString? And this path has a pointer which points to a share directory of the folder.
If there is an any alternate solution please let me know
Thank you

Comment: What is type of your cFilename object? Can you get a 'plain' string from it ?(i.e. does it have something like c_str() method?)

Comment: As a step towards QString - use conversion to std::string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195321/cannot-convert-findfiledata-cfilename-to-string

Comment: how do i convert cstring to qstring?

Comment: MFC CString? QString has a bunch of static fromXXX functions, just open QString header file and look which one appropriate. Be careful, CString itself depends on the compiling environment also.

Answer (score 1):

You need two steps: 
1. `CString` to `std::string`:

```
CString cString("Hello");
CT2CA convertedString(cstring);
std::string stdString(convertedString);
```

2. `std::string` to `QString`:

```
QString qtString = QString::fromStdString(stdString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the type of `cFilename`, but if is `std::string` you could do `QString::fromUtf8(cFilename.c_str())`. If it is a `const char*` then you could do `QString::fromUtf8(cFilename)`.

Comment: what if it is a CString? how to convert cString to QString?