# string& vs. wstring& in runtime_error

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I need my exception class, that inherits `runtime_class`, to accept `wstring&`. This is `MyExceptions.h`:

```
using namespace std;

class myExceptions : public runtime_error
{

public:
    myExceptions(const string &msg ) : runtime_error(msg){};
    ~myExceptions() throw(){};

};
```

I would like `myExceptions` to accept `wstring&` like this : `myExceptions(const **wstring** &msg )`. But when I run that, I got this error:

```
C2664: 'std::runtime_error(const std__string &): cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const std::wstring' to 'const std::string &'
```

I understand that `runtime_error` accepts `string&` and not `wstring&` as defined as following from [C++ Reference - runtime_error](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/runtime_error/):

```
> explicit runtime_error (const string& what_arg);
```

How can I use `wstring&` with in `runtime_error`?

Comment: how about writing another constructor taking wstring as parameters?

Comment: Minor clarification:  that's a compile error, it just happens to have the words runtime in the error message.

Comment: I thought so, but I don't know how to do it. I should overwrite it in this way? explicit runtime_error(const wstring& msg); and where? in MyExceptions.h class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to pass to `runtime_error` a conventional message and handle your wstring message directly in your `myExceptions` class:

```
class myExceptions : public runtime_error {
public:
    myExceptions(const wstring &msg ) : runtime_error("Error!"), message(msg) {};
    ~myExceptions() throw(){};

    wstring get_message() { return message; }

private:
    wstring message;
};
```

Otherwise you could write a private static member function that converted from wstring to string and use it to pass the converted string to `runtime_error`'s constructor. However, as you can see from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804298/how-to-convert-wstring-into-string), it's not a very simple thing to do, possibly a bit too much for an exception constructor.