# LWPSTR to CONST CHAR* help needed

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert a const char pointer to a constant wide string pointer. Here is my code.

```
double ret;
const wchar_t* file;
file = const wchar_t* (file_old);
```

I get something that says this: "Error, type name not allowed." over the const.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually convert the contents to which the pointer points to wide characters. The easiest way to do that is probably to put the narrow version into a string and convert using `wstring_convert` as detailed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18374698/82320

Comment: Ok, I got it figured by replacing all the wchar_t stuff with LPCWSTR, but now I get this error: 1>dllmnain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PlaySoundW@12, do you know of that error? I would rate your answer up, but I don't have enough rep.