# C++ Issue, Converting wchar_t* to string

Tags: c++, unicode, tokenize

I am having a problem here. This is in Unicode. I have a stringtable that has values in it, separated by `;`. I've been at this all day and I always end up with immediate runtime errors.

Stringtable looks like:

```
`blah;blah;foo;bar;car;star`
```

Then the code:

```
// More than enough size for this
const int bufferSize = 2048;

// Resource ID to a StringTable
int resid = IDS_MAP;
wchar_t readMap[bufferSize];            
resid = LoadString(NULL, resid, readMap, bufferSize);  

wchar_t* line;
line = wcstok(readMap,L";");

while (line != NULL) {

    line = wcstok(NULL,L";");
    wstring wstr(line); // Problem
    string str(wstr.begin(), wstr.end()); // Problem

    MessageBox(0,line,0,0) // No problem
}
```

The trouble is when I try to convert `wchar_t* line` to a `wstring`, to `string`. If I uncomment those two lines, it runs fine and message box shows properly.

Any ideas? Asking this question here was my last resort. Thanks.

Comment: string is narrow characters. It's not compatible with wchar_t. you might be more productive with wstring.

Comment: @bmargulies is there a way to convert wstring to string? I thought I saw some examples of that somewhere, but also didn't work for me. Would converting with `MultiByteToWideChar` be the way to go? (I haven't tried it)

Comment: about `wstring` to `string`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804298/how-to-convert-wstring-into-string

Comment: Other way around, you seem to be looking for `WideCharToMultiByte`. Note that it's a C API so using it correctly is slightly cumbersome.

Comment: You need to check `line != NULL` before writing `wstring wstr(line)`

Comment: I'm probably missing something here, but if `LoadString` is `LoadStringW` (Unicode) then `MessageBox` is `MessageBoxW`. The issue is not _how_ to convert to `char*` but _why_.

Comment: @M.M Ill add it before the first iteration. @MSalters the whole program is unicode (as I am using GDI+.) The reason for the conversion is because I need to do string comparisons. I have a block of text to read 1 character at a time, and another I need to read chunk at a time. The main problem was the converting string part, like `if (wstring == L"string").`

Comment: @EvanCarslake you made it worse. There needs to be a check in between `line = wcstok`... and `wstring wstr(line);`

Comment: @M.M I didn't update my code, but yeah I did misunderstand where to check null, and is updated. 

and even though I am using Unicode throughout the program, I decided to use Ansi for this, a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement:

```
line = wcstok(readMap,L";");
```

Reads the first delimited `line` in the buffer. OK.

However, in your loop, this statement:

```
line = wcstok(NULL,L";");
```

Is at the *top* of the loop and is thus *throwing away* that first line on the 1st iteration and then reading the *next* delimited `line`.  Eventually, your loop will reach the end of the buffer and `wcstok()` will return NULL, but you are not checking for that condition before using `line`:

```
line = wcstok(readMap,L";"); // <-- reads the first line

while (line != NULL) {

    line = wcstok(NULL,L";"); // <-- 1st iteration throws away the first line
    wstring wstr(line); // <-- line will be NULL on last iteration

    //...
}
```

The `line = wcstok(NULL,L";");` statement needs to be moved to the *bottom* of the loop instead:

```
wchar_t* line = wcstok(readMap, L";");

while (line != NULL)
{
    // use line as needed...

    line = wcstok(NULL, L";");
}
```

I would suggest changing the `while` loop into a `for` loop to enforce that:

```
for (wchar_t* line = wcstok(readMap, L";"); (line != NULL); line = wcstok(NULL, L";"))
{
    // use line as needed...
}
```

On the other hand, since you are using C++, you should consider using `std:wistringstream` and `std:getline()` instead of `wcstok()`:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

// after LoadString() exits, resid contains the
// number of character copied into readMap...
std::wistringstream iss(std::wstring(readMap, resid));

std::wstring line;
while (std::getline(iss, line, L';'))
{
    // use line as needed...
}
```

But either way, this statement is just plain wrong:

```
string str(wstr.begin(), wstr.end()); // Problem
```

This statement will work *correctly* only if the `std::wstring` contains ASCII characters in the #0 - #127 range.  For non-ASCII characters, you *have* to perform a data conversion instead to avoid data loss for Unicode characters > U+00FF.

Since you are running on Windows, you can use the Win32 API `WideCharToMultiByte()` function:

```
std::wstring line;
while (std::getline(iss, line, L';'))
{
    std::string str;

    // optionally substitute CP_UTF8 with any ANSI codepage you want...
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, line.c_str(), line.length(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        str.resize(len);
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, line.c_str(), line.length(), &str[0], len, NULL, NULL);
    }

    // use str as needed...
    MessageBoxW(0, line.c_str(), L"line", 0);
    MessageBoxA(0, str.c_str(), "str", 0);
}
```

Or, if you are using C++11 or later, you can use the `std::wstring_convert` class (only for UTF-8/16/32 conversions, though):

```
#include <locale> 

std::wstring line;
while (std::getline(iss, line, L';'))
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> conv;
    std::string str = conv.to_bytes(line);

    // use str as needed...
    MessageBoxW(0, line.c_str(), L"line", 0);
    MessageBoxA(0, str.c_str(), "str", 0);
}
```