# parameters sent don't match the function def

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

I have the following scenario that works in Visual C++ 10 but not with GCC on Linux:

call:

```
value& v;
wstring fn(L"");
char_conv::str_to_wstr( path, fn );

parse( v, ifstream( fn.c_str() ) ); //<-- ERROR
```

funct def:

```
inline std::string parse(value& out, std::istream& is){...}
```

This is the error I get:

```
In member function ‘std::string PrintInvoker::extractParameter(const std::string&, picojson::value&)’:
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(const wchar_t*)’
```

Comment: `ifstream` just does not accept wide strings: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream

Comment: You're also trying to bind a temporary to a non-const lvalue reference, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::idstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) has the following constructors:

```
basic_ifstream();
explicit basic_ifstream( const char* filename,
            ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in );

explicit basic_ifstream( const string& filename,                                  
            ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in );

basic_ifstream( basic_ifstream&& other );

basic_ifstream( const basic_ifstream& rhs) = delete;
```

Now when you call `fn.c_str()` that returns a `wchar_t*` since `fn` is a `wstrgin`.  As you can see there are no overloads that take a `wchar_t*` so the compiler is giving you an error.

Looking at my copy of MSVS2015 it appears that Microsoft has added a constructor that does take a `wchar_t*` so that is why it works on there,

Comment: Thank you for helpful explanation. There is a way of converting to the needed type by the idstream's constructor. Or other solution  ?

Comment: @cristian Either change `fn` to a `std::string` or you can convert it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804298/how-to-convert-wstring-into-string