# How do I concatenate a string and wstring?

Tags: c++, string, concatenation, wstring

I have a wstring variable and a string variable in C++. I want to concatenate them both, but simply adding them together produces a build error. How can I combine them both? If I need to convert the wstring variable to a string, how would I accomplish this?

```
//A WCHAR array is created by obtaining the directory of a folder - This is part of my C++ project
WCHAR path[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, path, MAX_PATH);
PathCchRemoveFileSpec(path, MAX_PATH);

//The resulting array is converted to a wstring
std::wstring wStr(path);

//An ordinary string is created
std::string str = "Test";

//The variables are put into this equation for concatenation - It produces a build error
std::string result = wStr + str;
```

Comment: Following the Windows conventions the `std::string` is not able to represent the wide string, in general. If it is meant to be used as a filesystem path then that's *one* particular conversion, but if it's meant to be displayed to the user then that's *a different* conversion. So it depends very much on what you intend to use the `std::string` for, what's its **purpose**?

Comment: "ordinary string" is a strange term. Which character set and encoding do you want the result to be? If it's not a Unicode encoding (for example, UTF-8), you'll loose data because `GetModuleFileNameW` is going to be a counted sequence of UTF-16 code units.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert the `wstring` to a `string` first, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4804298/3425536):

```
std::string result = std::string(wStr.begin(), wStr.end()) + str;
```

or if `wStr` contains non-ASCII characters:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> converter;
std::string wStrAsStr = converter.to_bytes(wStr);
std::string result = wStrAsStr + str;
```

Comment: This conversion loses information in the general case, and depending on the conventions used it may produce an invalid `std::string` value (e.g. invalid bytes for UTF-8 encoding), and so recommending it without mentioning the limitations is a bit reckless.

Comment: Added a safer alternative.

Comment: :) Now it doesn't lose information, which is good, but since this is Windows programming it's no longer very useful: doesn't work as a path, and doesn't present properly in GUI stuff (I believe the streams can be configured to present it properly in a console, but not sure about that). It can however be used as e.g. serialization of the wide string. It all depends on the **purpose**, which the OP neglects to mention.