# C++, conversion from utility:string_t to std::string crashes on return

Tags: c++, json, string, type-conversion, casablanca

I am using casablanca library to serialize json values.

I tried making a conversion to std::string using `typedef std::wstring string_t` and [this to convert from wstring to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804298/how-to-convert-wstring-into-string/18374698#18374698). It's compiling fine but the program just crashes when executing the return line.

```
std::string getString()
{
    web::json::value cvalue;
    /* ----- code ----- */
    typedef std::wstring string_t;
    string_t outputString = cvalue.serialize();

    typedef std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> convert_type;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_type, wchar_t> converter;
    std::string converted_str = converter.to_bytes(outputString);

    return converted_str;
}
```

I can't understand why this is crashing. Below is the line calling that function.

```
std::string s = getString();
```

The program triggered a break point here at line `free(_Ptr)` in a file called xdebug. I don't really understand what it's saying here. Hope this helps clarify things for you.

```
template<class _Ty>
    void __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL _DebugHeapDelete(_Ty *_Ptr)
    {   // delete from the debug CRT heap even if operator delete exists
    if (_Ptr != 0)
        {   // worth deleting
        _Ptr->~_Ty();
        // delete as _NORMAL_BLOCK, not _CRT_BLOCK, since we might have
        // facets allocated by normal new.
        free(_Ptr);
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code to see where it crashes?

Comment: @NathanOliver Hi did my edit help? it crash on the return line. But I don't know what's going on behind it.

Comment: Take out the json stuff out of that function and just hard-code a string literal, maybe `L"abc123"` and assign it to `outputString`.  Does the function crash?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just tried that. It crashed at the same place.

Comment: @XTT Ignore the compilation errors, but I just tried this code in Visual Studio 2015: http://ideone.com/1STzFR  and the program works correctly.  Maybe you should tell us exactly what version of Visual Studio you're using?   Better yet, create a brand new console project, copy and paste the *exact* code you see at the link, build, and run.  If it runs, then there is something wrong with your json Visual Studio project.  Maybe a mismatched runtime library or something along those lines...

Comment: You almost certainly have heap corruption. The problem is probably elsewhere, and happened earlier in your application.

Comment: @XTT I was also going to mention heap corruption, especially if that simple example I gave works correctly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the C++ REST SDK there is a function to convert `utility::string_t` into a utf8 `std::string`: `utility::conversions::to_utf8string`

[reference documentation](http://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/namespaceutility_1_1conversions.html#ac8d51543ee17a75bc289040c802d51af)

Comment: very strange.  there isn't a single function that takes utility::string_t and outputs std::string.