# std::wofstream::open is not working on MAC/Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, osx-yosemite

I am using wide string file stream std::wofstream to open a file and read its contents. I used header fstream. But when i compile this code on XCode 7, it is showing following error

```
No matching member function for call to 'open'
```

my code was like

```
header used <fstream>

std::wofstream out;
out.open(filename, std::ios::binary); <--- error
* filename is wide char string
```

NOTE: It is working on windows fine with Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 2):

`std::wofstream` is just a `std::basic_ofstream` with a template type of `wchar_t`.  [`std::basic_ofstream::open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open) has two overloads per the standard

```
void open( const char *filename,
       ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out );
void open( const std::string &filename,                                  
       ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out );
```

As you can see neither of then take a `wchar_t*` or `std::wstring`.  I suspect MSVS added an overload to accommodate using `open` with wide strings where xcode did not.

You should have no issue passing a `std::string` or a `const char*` to `open()`

I would like to point out that there is no reason to construct the object and then call `open()`.  If you want to construct and open a file then just use the constructor which will do that.

```
std::wofstream out;
out.open(filename, std::ios::binary);
```

Becomes

```
std::wofstream out(filename, std::ios::binary);
```

Comment: so, should i convert filename to std::string ?

Comment: @Jai If you have it as a `std::wstring` then yes.  You can see how to do that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804298/how-to-convert-wstring-into-string