# Set execution character set for Visual C++ compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to set the *execution character set* for Visual C++ compiler?

### Problem

When trying to convert an (UCN) string literal to a wide string, a runtime crash happens when using Visual Studio 2015 for compilation:

```
std::string narrowUCN = "\u00E4\u00F6\u00FC\u00DF\u20AC\u0040";
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> convertWindows;
std::wstring wide = convertWindows.from_bytes(narrowUCN); // Unhandled C++ exception in xlocbuf, line 426.
```

Using `narrowUCN = u8"\u00E4\u00F6\u00FC\u00DF\u20AC\u0040"` works so I assume a problem with the execution character set?

Comment: You are trying to hammer 16-bit pigeons into 8-bit holes, a wing is bound to come off.  Just keep it simple with std::wstring wide = L"\u00e4...".

Comment: Hehe, nice metaphor. However when writing against interfaces that use narrow strings it wouldn't be meaningful to work with wide/u16/u32 strings and convert them to narrow? Is there a performance impact when using narrow strings which contain utf8 characters using more than one byte instead of wide strings?

Comment: You make it sound like you have a choice.  You don't.  If the library requires 8-bit holes *and* understands utf-8 then that's what you have to use.  Just let the compiler do the work.

Answer (score 3):

[Since Visual Studio 2015 Update 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/22/new-options-for-managing-character-sets-in-the-microsoft-cc-compiler/), it is possible to set the *execution character set* to UTF-8 using the compiler option `/utf-8`. Then the conversion of narrow string literals, that don't use `u8`, will work. This is because those string literals are then converted to UTF-8 instead of the system's codepage (which is the default behaviour of Visual C++ compiler).

The option `/utf-8` is a synonym for `/source-charset:utf-8` and `/execution-charset:utf-8`. From the link above:

> In those cases where BOM-less UTF-8 files already exist or where changing to a BOM is a problem, use the /source-charset:utf-8 option to correctly read these files.
>
> Use of /execution-charset or /utf-8 can help when targeting code between Linux and Windows as Linux commonly uses BOM-less UTF-8 files and a UTF-8 execution character set.

PS: Don't confuse this with the character set setting in the common project configuration page which only sets the Macros Unicode/MBCS (historical reasons).