# Storing math symbols into string c++

Tags: c++, string, math, symbols

Is there a way to store math symbols into strings in c++ ? 
I notably need the union/intersection symbols.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're looking for Unicode.

Comment: Decide on your *encoding* and away you go. `std::wstring` might be the way forward. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string. Also research UTF-16.

Comment: Unicode will have code points. However you also need to be able to display the symbols. Whilst a modern computer will certainly have fonts installed, actually finding and accessing the display facilities might be quite difficult.

Comment: @Malcolm, what's "difficult" about `std::wcout << L"∩\n";`?

Comment: `std::cout << "∩\n";` is simpler and works on sane systems (meaning not Windows)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, as follows:

```
std::string unionChar = "∪";
std::string intersectionChar = "∩";
```

They are just characters but don't expect this code to be portable. You could also use Unicode, as follows:

```
std::string unionChar = u8"\u222A";
std::string intersectionChar = u8"\u2229";
```

Comment: An answer to the question absolutely, positively needs to mention character encodings. And the 'new' C++11 [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) types. Sorry, -1 for being incomplete. And wrong.

Comment: `std::string unionChar2 = u8"\u222A";` would be better. At least that way you know you can accommodate all the unicode characters in the string. But you'll [need conversions](http://utf8everywhere.org/). If I try `std::string unionChar = "\u222A";` on my platform it tries to stuff the character into an 8 bit char and converts it to `0x3f` i.e. `?`. But with `std::string unionChar2 = u8"\u222A";` I get `0xe2 0x88 0xaa` [which is good UTF8 for this character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/222a/index.htm).

Comment: It is wrong because you are assuming an execution character set that is compatible with your string literal. Try `std::string unionChar = "\u222A";` in Visual Studio and see what's coming out of it. (Hint: [You are trying to hammer 16-bit pigeons into 8-bit holes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739267/set-execution-character-set-for-visual-c-compiler#comment74523463_43739267)).

Comment: @IInspectable in theory, it's not wrong to assume it's not 1994 anymore and "multibyte" means UTF-8. In practice, there's Visual Studio.

Comment: @Cubbi: The problem isn't Visual Studio. The problem is the code in this proposed answer, which is wrong (and can be made correct, for Visual Studio and any other compiler). I have posted a link to the C++11 [string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) in my first comment already.

Comment: @IInspectable The code is correct. C++11 attempted to work around Visual Studio's defects, with mixed success.

Comment: @Cubbi: Which *"defect"* do you have in mind, specifically? It sounds a fair bit unlikely, that the C++ committee would vote for changes, that are meant to fix a single compiler only. References to the specific language rule(s) that Microsoft's compiler violates (pertaining to the discussion at hand) would help make a convincing point.

Comment: @IInspectable no multibyte strings (the point you brought up here, finally fixed with the non-default(!) option /utf-8), no wide strings (wchar_t cannot be 16-bit as of 1996, and wstring cannot use UTF-16 ever -  see lex.ccon etc).. And because neither kind of strings were supported, there are no Unicode locales or standard I/O, until C++11 patched a few (far too few) things with <codecvt> and u8/u/U literals. Arguably, C++98 was wrong in making much of it implementation-defined. Anyway, this is going too far off-topic

Answer (score 2):

This seemingly simple question is actual a tangle of multiple questions:

> What character set to use?

Unicode is almost certainly the best choice nowadays.

> What encoding to use?

C++ `std::strings` are strings of `char`s, but you can decide how those `char`s correspond to "characters" in your character set.  The default representation assumed by the language and the system is could be ASCII, some random code page like Latin-1 or Windows-1252, or UTF-8.

If you're on Linux or Mac, your best bet is to use UTF-8.  If you're on Windows, you might choose to use wide strings instead (`std::wstring`), and to use UTF-16 as the encoding.  But many people suggest that you [always use UTF-8](http://utf8everywhere.org/) in `std::string`s even on Windows, and simply convert from and to UTF-16 as needed to do I/O.

> How to specify string literals in the code?

To store UTF-8 in older versions of C++ (before C++11), you could manually encode your string literals like this:

```
const std::string subset = "\xE2\x8A\x82";
```

To store UTF-8 in C++11 or newer, you use the `u8` prefix to tell the compiler you want UTF-8 encoding.  You can use escaped characters:

```
const std::string subset = u8"\u2282";
```

Or you can enter the character directly into the source code:

```
const std::string subset = u8"⊂";
```

I tend to use the escaped versions to avoid worrying about the encoding of the source file and whether all the editors and viewers and IDEs I use will consistently understand the source file encoding.

If you're on Windows and you choose to use UTF-16 instead, then, regardless of C++ version, you can specify wide string literals in your code like this:

```
const std::wstring subset = L"\u2282";  // or L"⊂";
```

> How to display these strings?

This is very system dependent.

On Mac and Linux, I suspect things will generally just work.

In a console program on Windows (e.g., one that just uses `<iostreams>` or `printf` to display in a command prompt), you're probably in trouble because the legacy command prompts don't have good Unicode and font support.  (Maybe this is better on Windows 10?)

In a GUI program on Windows, you have to make sure you use the "Unicode" version of the API and to give it the wide string.  ("Unicode" is in quotation marks here because the Windows API documentation often uses "Unicode" to mean a UTF-16 encoded wide character string, which isn't exactly what Unicode means.)  So if you want to use an API like `TextOut` or `MessageBox` to display your string, you have to make sure you do two things:  (1) call the "wide" version of the API, and (2) pass a UTF-16 encoded string.

You solve (1) by explicitly calling the wide versions (e.g., `TextOutW` or `MessageBoxW`) or by making your you compile with "Unicode" selected in your project settings.  (You can also do it by defining several C++ preprocessor macros instead, but this answer is already long enough.)

For (2), if you are using `std::wstring`s, you're already done.  If you're using UTF-8, you'll need to make a wide copy of the string to pass to the output function.  Windows provides `MultiByteToWideChar` for making such a copy.  Make sure you specify `CP_UTF8`.

For (2), do *not* try to call the narrow versions of the API functions themselves (e.g., `TextOutA` or `MessageBoxA`).  These will convert your string to a wide string automatically, but they do so assuming the string is encoded in the user's current code page.  If the string is really in UTF-8, then these will do the wrong thing for all of the "interesting" (non-ASCII) characters.

> How to read these strings from a file, a socket, or the user?

This is very system specific and probably worth a separate question.