# how to get value from BSTR*

Tags: visual-c++

I have a BSTR*. how to get the value from the BSTR* to std::string so that I can print it to console?

```
BSTR* ptr;
HRESULT result = objPtr->GetValue(ptr);
//need to print to console the value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to pull this off; here's a simple example making use of the [_bstr_t Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx) to effect the conversion from `BSTR*` to [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <comutil.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib,"comsuppw.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const BSTR* const pbstr = new BSTR(::SysAllocString(L"Hello World"));

    if (pbstr)
    {
        const std::string stdstr(_bstr_t(*pbstr, true));

        std::cout << stdstr << std::endl;

        ::SysFreeString(*pbstr);
        delete pbstr;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::wcout << ptr;
```

should work because it is compatible to an wchar_t*.
You can also construct a `std::wstring` of an BSTR that is no `nullptr`.

If you wish to create a `std::string` of it you can check outher questions like
[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804298/how-to-convert-wstring-into-string) but be aware of the ideas of encoding. BSTR is encoded as UTF-16.

Comment: Appreciate your std::wcout answer. But how to convert it to std::string?