# Calling c++ function from python

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

I'm trying to call a C++ function from my Python code, if I pass a Boolean or an `int` it works perfectly, but if I send a string, it only prints the first character.
I am compiling with:

```
g++ -c -fPIC foo.cpp -Wextra -Wall -o foo.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -o libfoo.so foo.o
python3 fooWrapper.py
```

Here is the C++ and Python code:

Python:

```
from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./libfoo.so")
lib.Foo_bar("hello")
```

c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

void bar(char* string){
    printf("%s", string);
}

extern "C" {
    void Foo_bar(char* aString){
        bar(aString);
    }
}
```

I'm aware of the `Boost` Library, but i couldn't manage to download it, and this way works well excepts for strings. 
Thank you for your help

Comment: Tell me, what does `%i` do?

Comment: Also, why are you claiming this is C++ when you're essentially writing C?

Comment: Just changed to `%s` , was an old try with ints.

Comment: Because this is only a small part of the code, it's a test, but i saw I had to declare it as `extern "C"` to be able to cal it, but I can use any c++ in the `bar` function

Comment: You should consider filing a documentation bug against Python. [\[Python 3\] Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) in their manual does not appear treat the subject. `wchar_t` is shown in one place but not explained. `wchar_t` and wide chars are not explained.

Comment: @jww that's not the place. I've added that into my code

Comment: **To those voting to close:** This is not a typo, it was a lack of understanding what's needed for calling C++ functions from Python. Even if you consider it a typo, it is not one that was "resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers". The accepted answer is quite likely to help future visitors with a similar problem. While there could in all likelihood be a duplicate for this question (I haven't looked), it should not be closed as "typo: unlikely to help future readers".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that strings are passed as pointers to *[`wchar_t` wide characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_wchar_p)* in Python 3. And in little-endian system your string can be coded in binary as

```
"h\0\0\0e\0\0\0l\0\0\0l\0\0\0o\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
```

Which, when printed with `%s` will stop at the first null terminator.

---

For UTF-8-encoded byte strings (`char *`) [you need a `bytes` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_char_p). For example:

```
lib.Foo_bar("hello".encode())
```

or use bytes literals:

```
lib.Foo_bar(b"hello")
```

---

Even better if you had specified the correct argument types:

```
from ctypes import cdll, c_char_p
foo_bar = cdll.LoadLibrary("./libfoo.so").Foo_bar
foo_bar.argtypes = [c_char_p]
foo_bar(b"hello\n")
foo_bar("hello\n")
```

when run will output the following:

```
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 5, in <module>
    foo_bar("hello\n")
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

i.e. the latter call that uses a string instead of `bytes` would throw.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that worked really well !

Answer (score 1):

You may also process Python3 strings in C++ directly using the `wchar_t` type. In that case, you need to do any necessary conversions in C++ like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

void bar(wchar_t const* aString)
{
    // Kudos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18374698
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert;

    std::cout << convert.to_bytes(aString) << std::endl;
}

extern "C" {
    void Foo_bar(wchar_t const* aString)
    {
        bar(aString);
    }
}
```

You will lose Python2 compatibility, however.