# Convert std::basic_string<Char> to string

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, mediainfo

While MediaInfoDLL returns metadata (Sampling Rate, Channels, Stream Size, Title...) in `std::basic_string<Char>` format, I need to convert to string to be able to process it later. For example `mi.Get(Stream_Audio, 0, __T("Performer"))` returns "Artist Name" in `std::basic_string<Char>` format.

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What exactly is `Char` in your question?  Is it equivalent to the builtin type `char`?  If so, I have some good news...

Comment: Also, can you provide a link to the API documentation for the library you're using?  It would help tremendously to see the exact declaration of `mi.Get`.  For example, what is the type of `mi`?

Comment: Yes, this is builtin type char. For what I know, there's not  API documentation for this library

Comment: What do you mean by “string”? `std::string` is a typedef name for `std::basic_string<char>`.

Comment: FYI in most builds (it is tweakable if built from source) it is mapped to wchar_t.

Answer (score 2):

Reading through the [MediaInfoLib library's](https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfoLib) C++ code, it seems there are two possibilities.  The library defines a type alias `String`, and this is the type you're seeing.

First, [here is the definition](https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfoLib/blob/fa8cba8feb37539f7c1d0b6a3c6b53449a69e5c9/Source/MediaInfo/MediaInfo_Const.h#L112-L128) of the `Char` and `String` types:

```
namespace MediaInfoLib {

/* ... */

//Char types
#undef  __T
#define __T(__x)     __T(__x)
#if defined(UNICODE) || defined (_UNICODE)
    typedef wchar_t Char;                    ///< Unicode/Ansi independant char
    #undef  __T
    #define __T(__x) L ## __x
#else
    typedef char Char;                       ///< Unicode/Ansi independant char
    #undef  __T
    #define __T(__x) __x
#endif

typedef std::basic_string<MediaInfoLib::Char> String;  ///< Unicode/Ansi independant string

/* ... */

}  // end namespace
```

If the macro `UNICODE` or `_UNICODE` was defined when the library was built, then the type is `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`, which is [`std::wstring` in the standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

To convert this to `std::string`, please see this question:
[How to convert wstring into string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804298/how-to-convert-wstring-into-string)

The [simplest answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18374698/1718575) uses `std::wstring_convert`.

If the macro `UNICODE` or `_UNICODE` was NOT defined when the library was built, then `MediaInfoLib::Char` is the type `char`, and the `MediaInfoLib::String` type is `std::basic_string<char>` is already `std::string`.  That is, in this case, the return type is *already std::string*.

Answer (score 0):

> Convert `std::basic_string<Char>` to string ... Yes, this is builtin type char

If `Char` is an alias of `char`, then `std::basic_string<Char>` is already `std::string`. No conversion is needed, since it is the same type.

Answer (score 0):

`MediaInfo` has `ZenLib` as a dependency, which in turn has its own `Ztring`. You can do something like this:

```
#include "ZenLib/Ztring.h"
```

```
MediaInfoLib::String mediainfoString = mi.Get(Stream_Audio, 0, __T("Performer"));
ZenLib::Ztring zenlibZtring(mediainfoString);
std::string stdString = zenlibZtring.To_UTF8(); // or To_Local()
```

You can be slightly more efficient by directly using `Ztring` and skipping the intermediary `mediainfoString`.

p.s. `std::wstring_convert()` was deprecated in c++17 and should probably *not* be used.