# How to convert std::string to wchar_t*

Tags: c++

```cpp
std::regex regexpy("y:(.+?)\"");
std::smatch my;
regex_search(value.text, my, regexpy);
y = my[1];

std::wstring wide_string = std::wstring(y.begin(), y.end());
const wchar_t* p_my_string = wide_string.c_str();
wchar_t* my_string = const_cast<wchar_t*>(p_my_string);

URLDownloadToFile(my_string, aDest);
```

I'm using `Unicode`, the encoding of the source string is `ASCII`,  `UrlDownloadToFile` expands to `UrlDownloadToFileW (wchar_t*)` the code above compiles in debug mode, but with a lot of warnings like:

```
warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'wchar_t' to 'const _Elem', possible loss of data
```

So do I ask, how I could convert a `std::string` to a `wchar_t`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert wstring into string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804298/how-to-convert-wstring-into-string)

Comment: How to convert wstring into string?

Comment: Or even this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573834/c-convert-string-or-char-to-wstring-or-wchar-t

Comment: Is this in general, or is it on a specific platform?  Can you use SDKs like ICU?  Do you know the encoding of the source string (simple ASCII?  UTF-8?  8895-1? 1252? 437?)

Comment: @Eljay simple ASCII

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  The `UrlDownloadToFileW` should have no issues with any conversion warnings if you are giving it the arguments of the correct type.  Second thing is that [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775123(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) does not show a two argument function.

Comment: You don't need the `const_cast` anyway, because `UrlDownloadToFileW()` takes a `const wchar_t*` to begin with, so `c_str()` will work fine as-is: `URLDownloadToFile(wide_string.c_str(), ...);`

Comment: What is `y`? From the statement `y = my[1];` it seems that `y` is a `std::sub_match`, but `sub_match` does not have `begin` or `end` methods.

Comment: @RaymondChen `std::sub_match` has a [conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match/str) for `std::string` in this example

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. That was the missing bit. The declaration was `std::string y = my[1];` I was using `auto y = my[1];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you don't need the `const_cast`, as `URLDownloadToFileW()` takes a `const wchar_t*` as input, so passing it `wide_string.c_str()` will work as-is:

```cpp
URLDownloadToFile(..., wide_string.c_str(), ...);
```

That being said, you are constructing a `std::wstring` with the individual `char` values of a `std::string` as-is.  That will work *without data loss* only for ASCII characters <= 127, which have the same numeric values in both ASCII and Unicode.  For non-ASCII characters, you need to actually *convert* the `char` data to Unicode, such as with `MultiByteToWideChar()` (or equivilent), eg:

```cpp
std::wstring to_wstring(const std::string &s)
{
    std::wstring wide_string;

    // NOTE: be sure to specify the correct codepage that the
    // str::string data is actually encoded in...
    int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), s.size(), NULL, 0);
    if (len > 0) {
        wide_string.resize(len);
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), s.size(), &wide_string[0], len);
    }

    return wide_string;
}

URLDownloadToFileW(..., to_wstring(y).c_str(), ...);
```

That being said, there is a simpler solution.  If the `std::string` is encoded in the user's default locale, you can simply call `URLDownloadToFileA()` instead, passing it the original `std::string` as-is, and let the OS handle the conversion for you, eg:

```cpp
URLDownloadToFileA(..., y.c_str(), ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a cross-platform solution. You can use `std::mbtowc`.

```
std::wstring convert_mb_to_wc(std::string s) {
    std::wstring out;
    std::mbtowc(nullptr, 0, 0);
    int offset;
    size_t index = 0;
    for (wchar_t wc;
           (offset = std::mbtowc(&wc, &s[index], s.size() - index)) > 0;
           index += offset) {
        out.push_back(wc);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Adapted from an example on cppreference.com at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbtowc .