# How to pass wide characters to libcurl API which takes only const char*?

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl, wstring

I'm using `libcurl` to upload some files to my server. I need to handle files whose names are in different languages e.g. Chinese, Hindi, etc. For that, I need to handle files using `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`.

`libcurl` has a function with a [prototype](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_mime_filename.html) like below:

```
CURLcode curl_mime_filename(curl_mimepart *part, const char *filename);
```

But I cannot pass `std::wstring::c_str()` because it will return `const wchar_t*` instead of `const char*`.

Edit: I still don't know what encoding scheme is used by the server as it is a third party app so I used `std::wstring` for handling filenames and the conversion from `std::wstring` to `std::string` is done by the below function I [found on this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804298/how-to-convert-wstring-into-string).

```
std::string ws2s(const std::wstring& wstr)
{
    using convert_typeX = std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_typeX, wchar_t> converterX;

    return converterX.to_bytes(wstr);
}
```

Comment: Depends on how the server accept it I think. Probably UTF8?

Comment: MIME has several conflicting standards over how non-ASCII characters are handled. What particular encoding(s) does your server actually support for Unicode filenames? If you don't know, ask the server admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curl_mime_filename` is not suitable for

> files whose names are in different languages e.g. Chinese, Hindi, etc.

It is suitable for ASCII and UTF-8 file name encodings only.

The job of `curl_mime_filename` is:

1. Detect the data content type, for example `file.jpg` → `image/jpeg`.
2. Add the multipart header `Content-Disposition`, for example `Content-Disposition: attachment; name="data"; filename="file.jpg"`. The encoding to `filename=` is not set.

---

- If you know the server encoding, then encode the chars `0x80 .. 0xff` in filename to `%80 .. %ff`:

  1. Example for UTF8: `Naïve file.txt` → `Na%C3%AFve%20file.txt`.
  2. Example for UCS2: `file.txt` → `%00f%00i%00l%00e%00.%00t%00x%00t`.

  Pass the encoded file name to `curl_mime_filename`.
- If you do not know the server encoding used or whish to use another encoding, then do not use `curl_mime_filename`.

  1. Use the desired char encoding for the filename.
  2. Encode the chars over `0x7f` like above.
  3. Use `curl_mime_headers` and set the headers mentioned above, use `filename*=` instead of `filename=`.

     ```
     struct curl_slist *headers = nullptr;
     headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: image/jpeg");
     headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"data\"; filename*=UTF-8''Na%C3%AFve%20file.txt");
     curl_mime_headers(part, headers, true);
     ```

Answer (score 0):

According to the CURL [wiki](https://github.com/curl/curl/wiki/libcurl-and-expected-string-encodings), `curl_mime_filename` expects `filename` to be in `codepage determined by context on either the local or remote side`. That means you have to ask server what encoding it uses and use that encoding too.