# Jsoncpp reading some characters as escaped unicode

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

Problem: I'm trying to extract a line from a json file and put it in a txt file. The issue is that certain characters are represented as escaped unicode instead of the standard unicode representation.

Attempts to fix this issue: I'm not exactly sure what is causing this issue. My guess is that it has something to do with JSONcpp being unicode 8 instead of unicode 16. I looked up on ways to convert a unicode 8 string to 16 by looking up [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804298/how-to-convert-wstring-into-string](https://stackoverflow.com). But that didn't work either. I also looked up if it was something with the file stream system [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream](https://stackoverflow.com) and that did not get me my desired results either.
](https://stackoverflow.com)
example code...

```
    Json::Value root;
    Json::Reader reader; 
    Json::StyledStreamWriter writer;
    ifstream  file("fileName");
    //wifstream  file(L"fileName");
    //ifstream<wchar_t> file("FileName");
    std::fstream txtFile("txtFileName");
    reader.parse(file, root);
    Json::Value events = root["events"];

//contains "He said “stop!”."
tempDialogue = events[eventIndex]["pages"][pageIndex]["list"][listIndex]["parameters"][0];
writer.write(txtFile, tempDialogue);
file.close();
txtFile.close();
```

text File than contains
"He said \u201cHey stop \u201d."
expected result
"He said “stop!”."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON specification allows non-ascii characters to be represented in the native UTF-8 encoding or as a `\uXXXX` escape.
JSONCPP converts everything into the native UTF-8 encoding internally, so what you are seeing is result of the default configuration of the StreamWriter.

You can construct a StreamWriter yourself that emits only the UTF-8 form using a StreamWriterBuilder:

```
StreamWriterBuilder builder;
builder["emitUTF8"] = true;
std::unique_ptr<Json::StreamWriter> writer(builder.newStreamWriter())
writer->write(tempDialogue, &txtFile);
```

Comment: so with your changes, the last line  
writer->write(tempDialogue, txtFile);  
gives me a conversion argument error that states   
 " no suitable conversion function from  "std::fstream" to "json::OStream *" exists.

Comment: Take the address of `txtFile` instead, like I did in my edit.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks.
Can you explain why passing it by reference worked instead of passing it by value?

Comment: The `&` operator takes the **address**, which results in a `fstream*`, and `json::OStream` is a typedef for `std::ostream`.