# http requests are causing heap corruption?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, heap-corruption

I am trying to send some data to a php script from my c++ project like this:

```
void sendThatBitch()
{
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;
    LPSTR pszOutBuffer;
    vector <string>  vFileContent;
    BOOL  bResults = FALSE;
    HINTERNET  hSession = NULL,
        hConnect = NULL,
        hRequest = NULL;

    // Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
    hSession = WinHttpOpen(L"WinHTTP Example/1.0",
        WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

    // Specify an HTTP server.
    if (hSession)
    {
        cout << "WinHttpOpen\n";
        hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, L"example.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, 0);
    }

    // Create an HTTP request handle.
    if (hConnect)
    {
        cout << "WinHttpConnect\n";

        string req = "/script.php?data1=";
        req += DATA1;
        req += "&data2=";
        req += DATA2;
        req += '\0';

        WCHAR* str = new WCHAR(req.size() - 1);

        MultiByteToWideChar(0, 0, req.c_str(), req.size(), str, req.size());

        hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"GET", str, NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, NULL, NULL);
    }

    // Send a request.
    if (hRequest)
    {
        cout << "WinHttpOpenRequest\n";
        bResults = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    // End the request.
    if (bResults)
    {
        cout << "WinHttpSendRequest\n";
        bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, NULL);
    }

    // Close any open handles.
    if (hRequest)
    {
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
    }

    if (hConnect)
    {
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
    }

    if (hSession)
    {
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
    }
}
```

Now my problem here is something that occurs most of the time, but not always. Sometimes the data does get sent but when I do get an error it looks like this:

> Critical error detected c0000374 application.exe has triggered a
>   breakpoint.
>
> First-chance exception at 0x77EFE653 (ntdll.dll) in application.exe:
>   0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x77F34268).
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x77EFE653 (ntdll.dll) in application.exe:
>   0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x77F34268).

This happens on eather `WinHttpOpenRequest` or `WinHttpSendRequest`. Does anybody have any idea about why this is happening most of the time?

note: the domain mentioned in this code is fake and not the one being used in the real code.

Comment: Try this: WCHAR* str = new WCHAR(req.size());

Comment: then I get: `First-chance exception at 0x756EF80A (KernelBase.dll) in application.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x005B5000.
Unhandled exception at 0x756EF80A (KernelBase.dll) in application.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x005B5000.`

Comment: I think you need to use the MultiByteToWideChar as describe by the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693010/problem-using-multibytetowidechar

Comment: use [] not () here `WCHAR* str = new WCHAR(req.size() - 1);` and remember to delete it with `delete []`.  Using a std::vector<WCHAR> would be easier though.

Comment: Well spotted Richard Critten, I think I may be going blind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the link of ChrisWard1000 in the comment above and its now working by doing like this:

```
if (hConnect)
{
    cout << "WinHttpConnect\n";

    string req = "/script.php?data1=";
    req += DATA1;
    req += "&data2=";
    req += DATA2;
    req += '\0';

    int wchars_num = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, req.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0);
    wchar_t* str = new wchar_t[wchars_num];

    MultiByteToWideChar(0, 0, req.c_str(), req.size(), str, req.size());

    hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect, L"GET", str, NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, NULL, NULL);

    delete[] str;
}
```

+1 for that suggestion, thank you guys.