# How do I delete a pointer after I use it to return as a normal variable of a function

Tags: c++, string, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have looked at similar questions, but they all assume that the return type is also a pointer.  I apologize if this is not worded well as I am kinda new to c++.

So I have the following function:

```
//Converts string to LPCTSTR for dialog box
LPCTSTR CAnotherAttemptDlg::convertToLPCTSTR(std::string conversion)
{

    size_t convertedChars = 0;
    const size_t newsizew = conversion.size() + 1;
    wchar_t* wcstring = new wchar_t[newsizew];
    mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, newsizew, conversion.c_str(), _TRUNCATE);
    return wcstring;

}
```

I'm sure you notice I am returning a pointer as the result, however the output shouldnt be a pointer, so I cannot delete the pointer outside the function through deleting the pointer it is assigned to, since it does not output to a pointer.  What is the best way to do this?

Note:  Just in case I am asked what this is supposed to do, It is converting a string to a LPCTSTR, which is the same as a wchar_t*

Edit:
For clarification, this is the block that is calling this function:

```
BOOL CAnotherAttemptDlg::OnInitDialog()
{

    string settingsLine;
    LPCTSTR defStrPath = L""; // = "C:\\Ste\\Runtime\\TestFiles";
    LPCTSTR defEndPath = L"";

    //grabs default start and end paths from FileTrams.ini, parses it into proper variables
    ifstream settingsStream("FileTrans.ini");

    while (getline(settingsStream, settingsLine)) {
        string delimiter = "=";
        string tokenOne = settingsLine.substr(0, settingsLine.find(delimiter)); 
        string tokenTwo = settingsLine.substr(settingsLine.find(delimiter) + 1, '10');

        if (tokenOne == "startPath") {
            defStrPath = convertToLPCTSTR(tokenTwo);
        }
        else if (tokenOne == "endPath") {
            defEndPath = convertToLPCTSTR(tokenTwo);
        }

    }

    

    settingsStream.close();
    


    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    SetWindowLong(this->m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(this->m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE) |  WS_SYSMENU);

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE1, defStrPath);
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE2, defEndPath);

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control

    delete[] defStrPath;
    delete[] defEndPath;
}
```

Comment: Can you return `std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]>` or `std::vector<wchar_t>`?

Comment: Why not `std::wstring`?

Comment: By the way, it depends on macros when building what `LPCTSTR` is. It might be `const char*`, or `const wchar_t*`.

Comment: @Eljay the function mbstowcs_s does not except a unique pointer.  Same for the vector

Comment: Smart pointer, vector or string classes doesn't matter. It's always possible to get the actual raw pointer when needed.

Comment: Note: the way you have worded this question conflates the pointer with the object pointed at. If this is how you are thinking about the problem, note that this is a twisty path that can lead you into bad places.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't know much about wstring, but I need specific varible types that work with filesystem.  It specifically asks for LPCTSTR.  I know that it is currently excepting wchar* as something it can use

Comment: To be honest, unless you want to use UTF-16 encoded characters and strings, you can use the "ASCII" functions explicitly. For every Windows API function that takes a string or character, there are two implementations. And if you need international characters and UTF-16, then use the wide-character types and functions directly instead. Like `LPCWSTR`, the functions with the `W` suffix, etc.

Comment: @user4581301 It is an odd situation.  LPCTSTR is the same as wchar_t*, but I'm assuming that LPCTSTR deallocates itself like string does, where the wchar_t* does not.  If I understand this right.

Comment: `LPCWSTR`, `LPCSTR` and `LPCTSTR` are just aliases for pointers. They are macros that will be replaced by the pointer type. So e.g. when you use `LPCWSTR` that will be replaced by `const wchar_t*`. And that's all you then have, a pointer to a character. It's not a C++ class object, there's no destructor, it will not be deleted automatically, there's no built-in life-time management.

Comment: Side note: That `T` stuff was a solution to a common problem back in the late 1990s when Microsoft had the Windows 9X OS products expecting 8-bit characters and the Windows NT OS products expecting 16-bit characters and folks wanted to be able to write the same code for both with minimal discomfort. Windows NT won that battle in the early 2000s, and since then `TEXT` has been more a hinderance than helpful. Stick to the wide character API end-to-end when possible.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see, so that's good to know.  The LPCTSTR variables were not deleted.  now they are but that did not solve the memory leak coming from this function, which confuses me a bit.  Added an edit to explain what I mean

Comment: `LPCTSTR defStrPath = L"";`  Don't initialize a pointer like this. Prefer `LPCTSTR defStrPath = nullptr` and let the proper function fills the pointer with a valid address.

Comment: @Ripi2 thanks for the advice!  I have taken that into consideration and adjusted my original code.  Do you have any ideas on how to fix the memory leak issue?

Comment: What toolchain are you using? `UNICODE` clearly being set for you, and that's generally an ego signature of Visual Studio. The most recent releases of Visual Studio have [Address Sanitizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-170) support, and that tool's brutally effective at ferreting out many types of memory errors.

Comment: `return TRUE;` must be called _after_ `delete []...`

Comment: You can access the underlying array of a unique_ptr that holds an array by using `p.get()` to get a pointer to its start.  You can access the underlying array of a vector by using `v.data()` to get a pointer to its start.

Comment: @user4581301 I am indeed using VS and it has done well on helping me find the memory leak, I'm just trying to figure out how to deallocate it after returning it.  I'm sorry if I misunderstood anything

Comment: @Eljay Unfortunately I cant use a vector or unique pointer in this situation because of the function mbstowcs_s not allowing unique pointers

Comment: As @Ripi2 points out, you cannot `delete`, or do anything else, after returning. When the function hits a `return` statement, the function is over. What you have here looks correct, other than the function exiting before it frees the memory.

Comment: @user4581301 how would I get around that though?  I need to return a pointer, but because of that I am unable to free the memory.

Comment: `OnInitDialog` consumes the strings returned by `convertToLPCTSTR`, so `convertToLPCTSTR` cannot be responsible for deleting the storage. ``OnInitDialog` is the only reasonable place for the `delete`, but if you return `std::wstring` and `SetDlgItemText(IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE1, defStrPath.str());` you don't need to take any action. The `wstring`s will do all the work for you when they go out of scope.

Comment: In general, if you're using `new` and `delete` and are not writing low-level infrastructure code where you need exceedingly fine-grained control, you are writing `std::wstring` for example, you're probably going to regret it.

Comment: `mbstowcs_s` allows for pointer, and unique_ptr can provide a pointer, and vector can provide a pointer.  You don't need to pass `mbstowcs_s` a unique_ptr, or a vector.

Comment: *but I need specific varible types that work with filesystem.* -- You are reading the documentation for these functions incorrectly.  What those functions want is *any* buffer, regardless of where it comes from, to point to an array of `T`.  The `std::wstring` and others mentioned would be almost useless if they didn't have a public way to access the underlying buffers that these classes have.  So `std::wstring` has the `c_str()` function, the `std::vector` has the `data()` function etc.  The designers of these classes knew what they were doing, since access to legacy C code is important.

Comment: "I need to return a pointer, but because of that I am unable to free the memory" You can delete the memory the pointer points to after a copy of the pointer is returned from the function. Don't think of it as deleting the pointer. You don't delete the pointer, just the dynamically allocated object(s) it points to.

Comment: Quick hack example: https://godbolt.org/z/KoT1Ed41W. Not making an answer out of this because I'm not 100% certain of the viability of `const size_t newsizew = conversion.size() + 1;`. You can call `mbstowcs_s`, the first time with the output buffer set to `NULL` to get the guaranteed size of the buffer in `convertedChars`.

Comment: @user4581301 So I am trying to do as you describe, I have replaced all instances of LPCTSTR to wstring and made changes so it says SetDlgItemText(IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE1, defStrPath.str()); though it did autocorrect to SetDlgItemText(IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE1, defStrPath.c_str());.  When running it throws a access violation error in xstring.    Not sure what's causing it.  Though I do think it might fix the issue once I find it.

Comment: Sorry about the earlier typo. See the link above. With the `wstring` you need to make sure you correctly size the `wstring` before you fill it. If you have correctly sized it, take the debugger up on the offer to debug and inspect the crash site with the stack trace to get more information on where the crash hit and the variables in play.

Answer (score 1):

My answer to your question is twofold...

### Technically: You can just `delete[]` it

As @someprogrammerdude and others indicate, what your method returns is a pointer to your freshly-allocated sequence of wchar_t's: An LPCWSTR, i.e. a (Long) Pointer to Const Wchar "STRing". You can apply  `delete[]` to the result of the invocation of this method.

But what I really wanted to tell you is:

### Normatively: Just don't do this.

There are multiple reasons why you should not be writing such a function, or method:

1. You should **avoid using raw `new` and `delete`** when they are not strictly necessary; this is C++ Core Guideline [R.11](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete). A main reason is, that it is easy to neglect to `delete` what you've allocated with a raw `new`, and there is no automated mechanism to ensure you do so.
2. You should also **avoid raw pointers which "own" memory**; this is C++ Core Guideline [R.3](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-ptr). Specifically, your function or method signatures should not yield ownership by returning a returning a pointer (which your function does). Rather,
3. **Manage memory automatically using ... RAII**; this is C++ Core Guideline [R.1](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-raii). Typically this means classes which allocate resources on construction and free them on destruction. For a string, specifically,
4. If you need a flexible buffer for your string characters rather than an `std::string` - use an appropriate buffer class `std::vector`, or maybe even an `std::stringstream`, depending on the context.
5. But actually - **your dialog class has no business converting people's strings**! After all, the `conversion` parameter is not known to be any string the class instance is at all concerned with. If you want to be able to convert a string of `char`'s to a string of `wchar_t`'s - that's certainly possible. Read this StackOverflow question:

   [C++ Convert string (or char*) to wstring (or wchar_t*)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2573834/1593077)

   and you'll find a simple enough answer (originally from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12903901/1593077)):

   ```
   std::wstring utf8_string_to_wstring(const std::string& str) {
       std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> converter;
       return converter.from_bytes(str);
   }
   ```

   this will work for UTF-8 text, and ASCII text in particular. But - it's deprecated as of C++17. I'd still use it myself, but another alterative is something more Microsoft-y, like the function suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59617138/1593077):

   ```
   std::wstring utf8_string_to_wstring(const std::string& str) {
       int count = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), 
           str.length(), nullptr, 0);
       std::wstring wstr(count, 0);
       MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), str.length(), 
           &wstr[0], count);
       return wstr;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

So with assistance from some people, I have gotten the program to work with no memory leaks.  What was suggested was to use wstring instead of LPCTSTR as it deallocates itself.

this is the current code:

```
BOOL CAnotherAttemptDlg::OnInitDialog()
{

    string settingsLine;
    wstring defStrPath = L""; // = "C:\\Ste\\Runtime\\TestFiles";
    wstring defEndPath = L"";

    //grabs default start and end paths from FileTrams.ini, parses it into proper variables
    ifstream settingsStream("FileTrans.ini");

    while (getline(settingsStream, settingsLine)) {
        string delimiter = "=";
        string tokenOne = settingsLine.substr(0, settingsLine.find(delimiter)); 
        string tokenTwo = settingsLine.substr(settingsLine.find(delimiter) + 1, '10');

        if (tokenOne == "startPath") {
            defStrPath = convertToLPCTSTR(tokenTwo);
        }
        else if (tokenOne == "endPath") {
            defEndPath = convertToLPCTSTR(tokenTwo);
        }

    }

    

    settingsStream.close();
    


    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    SetWindowLong(this->m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(this->m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE) |  WS_SYSMENU);

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE1, defStrPath.c_str());
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_MFCEDITBROWSE2, defEndPath.c_str());

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control

}

std::wstring CAnotherAttemptDlg::convertToLPCTSTR(std::string conversion)
{
    wstring temp = L"";

    size_t convertedChars = 0;
    const size_t newsizew = conversion.size() + 1;
    wchar_t* wcstring = new wchar_t[newsizew];
    mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, newsizew, conversion.c_str(), _TRUNCATE);
    temp = wcstring;
    delete[] wcstring;
    return temp;

}
```

An error to point out is that wstring seems to trip an error when using nullptr so I just initialized with a blank string, which might not be the best, but it works for now.

Comment: Initializing `wstring` will nullptr blows up because the closest matcing constructor for `wstring` (and `string`) is constructor that accepts a null-terminated character array. So it stupidly follows the rules and tries to consume a null pointer as a character array. BOOM! Instead initialize the string AFTER you have the string from `mbstowcs_s` or size the `wstring` appropriately and convert directly into it.