# Convert LPCSTR to std::wstring

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, wstring

ALL,

All questions here are talking about LPC`T`STR conversion.

But since the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/version-property-example-vc?view=sql-server-ver15 uses LPCSTR - I need to perform that conversion.

I have the code at the link working, but I need the conversion since the software I am writing is operating with std::wstring (it is cross-platform and cross-DBMS).

TIA!!

Comment: Plenty of solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691555/converting-narrow-string-to-wide-string

Comment: How to correctly do the conversion depends on the content of your LPCSTR, is it UTF-8, is it some Windows code page, is it ASCII? etc. etc. More detail is needed.

Comment: @john, I think it is some Windows code page - it is a string returning from the ADO `query`.

Comment: LPCSTR is Microsoft pointer to a C-Style string (a.k.a. array of ASCII characters terminated by nul).  The `wstring` type is for wide characters, i.e. encodings that don't fit within the ASCII set; usually represented by a 16-bit quantity.  So you are asking to convert a pointer to an 8-bit C-Style string to a 16-bit encoding.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, I don't think LPCSTR is the same as std::string. Do you?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, are you saying it is impossible to convert?

Comment: I did not say it is impossible.  I'm letting you know what needs to happen.  Search the internet for "lpcstr conversion wstring".

Comment: @Igor Yes, they are both narrow strings. LPCSTR and LPCTSTR are also the same when UNICODE is not defined.

Comment: @Igor Then you need MultiByteToWideChar as the code linked in the first comment uses. Ideally you would know which code page.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, UNICODE is defined in my case. (just curious - who does not define it in 21 century).

Comment: @Igor a lot of people, actually. Especially when maintaining legacy code that predates UNICODE, or just when writing code that doesn't need to deal with non-ASCII data.

Comment: @Igor Who uses `TCHAR` in the 21st century? *shrug*

Comment: @RetiredNinja, apparently MS ADO does. ;-) And I have another question - I looked at the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar, and it looks like I should use CP_OEMCP as the the OS default code page. Am I right?