# Struggling to convert vector<char> to wstring

Tags: c++, boost, utf-8, locale, utf-16

I need to convert utf16 text to utf8.  The actual conversion code is simple:

```
std::wstring in(...);
std::string out = boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<char, wchar_t>(in);
```

However the issue is that the UTF16 is read from a file and it may or may not contain BOM.  My code needs to be portable (minimum is windows/osx/linux).  I'm really struggling to figure out how to create a `wstring` from the byte sequence.

**EDIT:** this is not a duplicate of the linked question, as in that question the OP needs to convert a wide string into an array of bytes - and I need to convert the other way around.

Comment: I'm not sure, will [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573834/c-convert-string-or-char-to-wstring-or-wchar-t) help?

Comment: How do you convert from the `vector<char>` to a `wstring` ?

Comment: @SirDarius Well, this is exactly my question: how to get the `wstring` from the `vector<char>`?

Comment: why use `boost::locale` when you can use `std::locale` (C++11 introduced UTF-8 and UTF-16 character sets)?

Comment: @qdii I don't care what to use - I need to get a utf8 string from byte array containing utf16.  And it needs to be in a portable way (i.e. windows, OSX and unix/linux)

Comment: @gongzhitaao Won't help, as it's windows-specific.  I need this to work on linux and windows.

Comment: @qdii No, not a duplicate at all.  In that question the OP already has a wide string.  I have an array of bytes.

Comment: @AleksG oh ok, so your title is misleading, you are not struggling with converting utf16 utf8, but with reading from an utf16-encoded file into a widestring. Am I right?

Comment: @qdii I suppose, yes.  I updated the question.

Comment: @AleksG: your question is still misleading. Your code snippet suggests you are reading a UTF-16 encoded file and want to convert it to UTF-8, but what you said to @qdii says you want to read a UTF-16 encoded file and leave it in UTF-16 (that is what `std::wstring` uses on Windows. On some other platforms it uses UTF-32 instead - which is why `wchar_t` is not portable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use wide types at all in your case.

Assuming you can get a `char *` from your `vector<char>`, you can stick to bytes by using the following code:

```
char * utf16_buffer = &my_vector_of_chars[0];
char * buffer_end = &my_vector_of_chars[vector.size()];
std::string utf8_str = boost::locale::conv::between(utf16_buffer, buffer_end, "UTF-8", "UTF-16");
```

[between](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/locale/doc/html/group__codepage.html#ga7eda9058b8cbac9b05886bcc894faeff) operates on 8-bit characters and allows you to avoid conversion to 16-bit characters altogether.

It is necessary to use the `between` overload that uses the pointer to the buffer's end, because by default, `between` will stop at the first `'\0'` character in the string, which will be almost immediately because the input is UTF-16.

Comment: Hm, interesting thought.  I'll give it a try and post back.

Comment: This almost works.  Because the string contains latin chars as well (i.e. there are \0 bytes in the vector), I have to explicitly specify the end pointer: `boost::local::conv::between(&my_vector_of_chars[0], &my_vector_of_chars[vector.size()], "UTF-8", "UTF-16")`

Comment: Ouch, makes sense, of course, since there will be zero characters and no end pointer in the form I used in my answer, it's bound to fail, since between is gonna stop at the first null char, gonna fix this.