# Undefined reference to boost::locale:conv::between

Tags: c++, boost, locale

I am trying to follow the answer to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730823/struggling-to-convert-vectorchar-to-wstring) and use `boost::locale::conv::between` to get a UTF-8 string from `vector<char>` containing UTF-16 data.  My code is pretty much as in the answer (with some differences in how I get the `char *`:

```
char in[length + 1];
//... populate in with my source data
in[length] = '\0';
std::string out = boost::locale::conv::between((const char*)in, std::string("UTF-8"), std::string("UTF-16"));
```

This compiles fine, but during linking I get error

```
In function `boost::locale::conv::between(char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::locale::conv::method_type)':
/usr/local/include/boost/locale/encoding.hpp:186: undefined reference to `boost::locale::conv::between(char const*, char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::locale::conv::method_type)'
```

This doesn't look right to me.  On possibility I could think of is that I had boost 1.50 installed, so I installed latest 1.55 release - yet I get the same error.

Comment: Boost locale is not a header-only library, it has an actual library that you need to link with.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg D'oh! That would explain it; forgot to include the `-l` for boost_locale.  Post your commend as an answer - I will accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Boost locale is not a header-only library, it has an actual library that you need to link with.
Adding following flag to LDFLAGS helps:

```
-lboost_locale
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem. I think you should use the dynamic library instead of the static library.