# Combine std::wstring and function

Tags: c++, string, ascii, sfml, wstring

I'm creating text in SFML 2.1 (It doesn't really matter) in c++.

Setting a text string looks like that: `text.setString("something");`

Ok, but because my game language is Polish, I have to enter some characters like ą,ż,ł,ś,ć etc. , which are not 'supported' in my game's ASCII encoding.

Iv'e came up with this solution: `text.setString(L"śomęthińg");`

But problems appear when you try to combine wstring and string from another function. For example:

```
text.setString(L"Name: " + PlayerName() );
```

I've tried converting it to string or creating temporary variables, but either did not work, or it erased this 'special characters'...

FULL EXAMPLE:

```
std::string PlayerName()
{
    std::string name = "John";
    return name;
}

int main()
{
    sf::Text hello;
    hello.setString(L"Hello " + PlayerName() + L", how are you?");
    //I need to use L" "

    window.draw(hello);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please provide a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What type is returned by `PlayerName()`? Can you provide a code sample that lets us see what you're doing?

Comment: You need to convert `PlayerName()` to a wstring.  You can use the code from this post to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18597384/4342498

Comment: Basically what you're going to want to do is replace all `std::string` with `std::wstring` wherever possible :/  Actually, I just saw SFML has it's own string type.  Use _that_: [sf::String](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1String.php)

Comment: Isn't there any option to change Unicode or something related to it, in order to just use normal string in the whole project ?

Comment: @Bionicl: Visual Studio has a `Character Set: Use Unicode Character Set`, and it is completely unrelated and doesn't help you in the slightest here.

Comment: @Bionicl - That setting affects the `TCHAR`, `LP(C)TSTR`, `_T() macro` and things like that.  It has absolutely no effect on `std::string ` and `std::wstring`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it!

As @MooingDuck said, [SFML has it's own string type](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1String.php), which is very powerful in this type of problems.

The way I've did it:

```
std::string PlayerName()
{
    std::string name = "John";
    return name;
}

int main()
{
    sf::String helloText = L"Hello ";
    helloText += PlayerName();
    helloText += L", how are you?";

    sf::Text hello;
    hello.setString(helloText);

    window.draw(hello);
}
```

Thanks a lot for help!