# Find a pattern in incoming string(including special characters like °) in c++

Tags: c++, regex, string

I have a requirement in cpp where we need to search some pattern in incoming string and need to replace with corresponding values.Here comes the tricky part incoming string can contain special characters(like ° etc) and pattern can be single character or group of characters. Initially thought to store  pattern string and replacement value in Map but i am facing problems with special characters please let me know the correct approach to solve this problem.

example: ° need to be replace by "degrees"

int main() {

```
map<string,string> tempMap;
pair<string,string> tempPair;




tempMap.insert(pair<string,string>("°","degrees"));
tempMap.insert(pair<string,string>("one","two"));
tempMap.insert(pair<string,string>("three","four"));
typedef map<string,string>::iterator it_type;

string temp="abc°def";

for(it_type iterator = tempMap.begin(); iterator != tempMap.end(); iterator++)
{
    //cout << iterator->first << " " << iterator->second << endl;

    string::size_type found=temp.find(iterator->first);

      if (found!=string::npos)
      {

        temp.replace(found,1,iterator->second);
        cout << endl <<"after replacement   " << temp;
      }


}
```

}

output : after replacement   abcdegrees�def

in output getting specialcharacter, this is because special character ° occupying 2 bytes.

Comment: you can use vector<char> to store them and use vector push_back() to store untill input is new line character. Then you can manipulate which ever way you want.

Comment: What problems did you encounter with patterns like the ° character that you couldn't solve?

Comment: Are you asking for someone to write the code for you? Do you have code already that isn't working?

Comment: You might want to mention how the `°` and other such "special" characters are encoded: e.g. rtf-8, Unicode etc. (after which you should go find a library therefor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *wide character* support (`wstring`, `wcout`, and the `L`-prefixed string literals):

```
#include <map> 
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    map<wstring,wstring> tempMap;
    pair<wstring,wstring> tempPair;

    tempMap.insert(pair<wstring,wstring>(L"°", L"degrees"));
    tempMap.insert(pair<wstring,wstring>(L"one", L"two"));
    tempMap.insert(pair<wstring,wstring>(L"three", L"four"));
    typedef map<wstring,wstring>::iterator it_type;

    wstring temp = L"abc°def";

    for(it_type iterator = tempMap.begin(); iterator != tempMap.end(); iterator++) {
        wstring::size_type found = temp.find(iterator->first);
        if (found != wstring::npos) {
            temp.replace(found, 1, iterator->second);
            wcout << "after replacement   " << temp << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working fine, but how can i prefix L  dynamically to String

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573834/c-convert-string-or-char-to-wstring-or-wchar-t