# How to read a UTF-16 file and compare it's contents to a wchar_t* string literal defined with hex values

Tags: c++, hex, ifstream, utf-16, wchar-t

I have a file in UTF-16 (or UCS-2, doesn't really matter since it is UTF-16 LE as far as I know) encoding which I have downloaded from here: [http://www.humancomp.org](http://www.humancomp.org/unichtm/unichtm.htm)

I'd like to read the contents of that file into a `std::wstring`, which is my first problem: I haven't been able to read the file correcly yet. The read data always seems to be messed up.

Secondly, I'd like to compare the read `std::wstring` to a `const wchar_t*` string literal. And here, I am experiencing my second problem: How do I specify the `wchar_t` content via hex values?

The file which I want to turn into a `const wchar_t*` string literal has the following bytes (copied out of a hex editor)

```
FE FF 05 31 05 65 05 81 05 65 05 70 05 6B 00 20 05 6B 05 74 00 20 05 6C 05 61 05 7E 00 20 00 3F 05 82 05 72 05 6B 05 65 00 20 05 6C 05 61 05 7E 05 61 05 80 05 61 05 80 00 2C 00 0D 00 0A 05 3F 05 75 05 61 05 65 05 62 05 7D 00 20 05 79 05 7F 05 61 05 75 05 6B 00 20 05 6F 05 61 05 7D 05 6F 05 61 05 6E 05 6B 00 20 05 74 05 70 05 63 05 6B 05 65 00 2E 00 2E 00 2E 00 0D 00 0A 05 31 05 75 05 65 05 7A 05 70 05 7D 00 20 05 6F 00 3F 05 82 05 66 05 70 05 6B 00 20 05 74 05 70 05 6F 05 65 00 20 05 6B 05 65 05 6E 00 20 00 3F 05 61 05 7E 05 61 05 7F 05 80 00 2C 00 0D 00 0A 05 31 05 75 05 65 05 7A 05 70 05 7D 00 20 05 6F 00 3F 05 82 05 66 05 70 05 6B 00 20 00 3F 05 61 05 7E 05 61 05 7F 05 61 05 6C 00 20 05 74 05 70 05 6F 05 6B 05 65 05 89
```

Of course, I can't initialize the string literal with that. I tried to turn it into hex values and apply a `reinterpret_cast` to get a `const wchar_t*`

```
reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>("\xFE\xFF\x05\x31\x05\x65\x05\x81\x05\x65\x05\x70\x05\x6B\x00\x20\x05\x6B\x05\x74\x00\x20\x05\x6C\x05\x61\x05\x7E\x00\x20\x00\x3F\x05\x82\x05\x72\x05\x6B\x05\x65\x00\x20\x05\x6C\x05\x61\x05\x7E\x05\x61\x05\x80\x05\x61\x05\x80\x00\x2C\x00\x0D\x00\x0A\x05\x3F\x05\x75\x05\x61\x05\x65\x05\x62\x05\x7D\x00\x20\x05\x79\x05\x7F\x05\x61\x05\x75\x05\x6B\x00\x20\x05\x6F\x05\x61\x05\x7D\x05\x6F\x05\x61\x05\x6E\x05\x6B\x00\x20\x05\x74\x05\x70\x05\x63\x05\x6B\x05\x65\x00\x2E\x00\x2E\x00\x2E\x00\x0D\x00\x0A\x05\x31\x05\x75\x05\x65\x05\x7A\x05\x70\x05\x7D\x00\x20\x05\x6F\x00\x3F\x05\x82\x05\x66\x05\x70\x05\x6B\x00\x20\x05\x74\x05\x70\x05\x6F\x05\x65\x00\x20\x05\x6B\x05\x65\x05\x6E\x00\x20\x00\x3F\x05\x61\x05\x7E\x05\x61\x05\x7F\x05\x80\x00\x2C\x00\x0D\x00\x0A\x05\x31\x05\x75\x05\x65\x05\x7A\x05\x70\x05\x7D\x00\x20\x05\x6F\x00\x3F\x05\x82\x05\x66\x05\x70\x05\x6B\x00\x20\x00\x3F\x05\x61\x05\x7E\x05\x61\x05\x7F\x05\x61\x05\x6C\x00\x20\x05\x74\x05\x70\x05\x6F\x05\x6B\x05\x65\x05\x89");
```

but this doesn't work. It gives me bogus data.

I've also tried to create a `wchar_t` string literal directly:

```
L"\xFEFF\x0531\x0565\x0581\x0565\x0570\x056B\x0020\x056B\x0574\x0020\x056C\x0561\x057E\x0020\x003F\x0582\x0572\x056B\x0565\x0020\x056C\x0561\x057E\x0561\x0580\x0561\x0580\x002C\x000D\x000A\x053F\x0575\x0561\x0565\x0562\x057D\x0020\x0579\x057F\x0561\x0575\x056B\x0020\x056F\x0561\x057D\x056F\x0561\x056E\x056B\x0020\x0574\x0570\x0563\x056B\x0565\x002E\x002E\x002E\x000D\x000A\x0531\x0575\x0565\x057A\x0570\x057D\x0020\x056F\x003F\x0582\x0566\x0570\x056B\x0020\x0574\x0570\x056F\x0565\x0020\x056B\x0565\x056E\x0020\x003F\x0561\x057E\x0561\x057F\x0580\x002C\x000D\x000A\x0531\x0575\x0565\x057A\x0570\x057D\x0020\x056F\x003F\x0582\x0566\x0570\x056B\x0020\x003F\x0561\x057E\x0561\x057F\x0561\x056C\x0020\x0574\x0570\x056F\x056B\x0565\x0589"
```

This, again, ends up in bogus data. I'm not even sure if this is the correct way of specifying `wchar_t` data - combining 2 bytes?

Comment: The bytes of your file are in **UTF-16BE** (as evident by the presence of the UTF-16BE BOM).  If your string literal is in **UTF-16LE** instead, you will have to do a conversion before you can compare them. Your `reinterpret_cast` for the raw literal bytes is fine, except that you get garbage at the end because you are not including a null terminator in UTF-16: `\x00\x00`. Your `L"..."` literal is null terminated correctly.

Comment: To read a UTF-16BE encoded file into a `std::wstring`, use a `std::wifstream` that has been `imbue()`'ed with a `std::locale` object that represents UTF-16BE.  If you are using C++11, you can create a `std::locale` that uses the `std::codecvt_utf16` class with its `std::consume_header` flag enabled so it will account for the BOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution which was achieved with the help of the comment by Remy Lebeau:

```
// BOM: \xFEFF
auto utf16raw = L"\x0531\x0565\x0581\x0565\x0570\x056B\x0020\x056B\x0574\x0020\x056C\x0561\x057E\x0020\x003F\x0582\x0572\x056B";
std::wstring utf16str{utf16raw};
```

The BOM must be left out of the string.
The UTF-16 string, `utf16str` can be converted into an UTF-8 encoded string (and vice-versa) with the [UTF-8 CPP library available on Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/utfcpp/), for instance.

Comment: If C++11 or above is allowed, the standard library alone is all that is needed to convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18597384/6345 for reference.