# How to convert a string encoded in utf16 to a string encoded in UTF-8?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, encoding, utf-8

I have a string or a char[], but the it is encoded in utf-16, like this:

[image]

Now I want to convert it to utf-8 in a new string, Please help me! I already tried like this:

[image]

But the compiler tells me I have a problem. How to solve this problem?

Comment: it`s better to write a code as a code instead of using a picture. Aslo could you provide us error message that compiler generates ?

Comment: Besides what @Vlad said, what's `data` in your code?

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18597384/6345 (C++ Convert string (or char*) to wstring (or wchar_t*)) and adapt to your types if they don't match.

Comment: Insert the problem of the compiler into your question. Questions like "it doesn't work" would require some supernatural abilities from us. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is evident: you define `u16_str` as a `std::string` when `cvt.to_bytes()` expect a `std::u16string` (as the name of the variable suggest).

The following code works for me

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
 {
   std::u16string  u16_str { u"aeiuoàèìòùAEIOU" };

   std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char16_t>, char16_t> cvt;

   std::string  u8_str = cvt.to_bytes(u16_str);

   std::cout << u8_str << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```