# c++ wstring special characters

Tags: c++, json, cpprest-sdk

I'm using [cpprestsdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk) to work with JSON. During creation of JSON I have a problem with special characters like `Å`. For example:

```
json::value json;
std:string s = "ÅÅÅ";
std::wstring wstvalue(s.begin(), s.end());
json[L"key"] = json::value::string(wstvalue)
```

As JSON accepts only `std::wstring` I can't convert correctly regular string to wstring. The result of json.key is strange and not corresponds to initial ÅÅÅ value.
How I can convert correctly regular `std::string` to `std::wstring` with characters like Å ?

Comment: JSON usually likes to be in UTF-8. Use `std:string s = u8"ÅÅÅ";`, avoid using wide string functions elsewhere in JSON. You cannot display UTF-8 in Windows, so you have to convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16 when displaying text, or when getting user input.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2573845/4697115) I have founded the next solution using `std::mbstowcs`:

```
json::value json;
std:string s = "ÅÅÅ";
std::wstring wstvalue(s.size(), L' ');
wstvalue.resize(std::mbstowcs(&wstvalue[0], s.c_str(), s.size()));
json[L"key"] = json::value::string(wstvalue)
```