# Why mask a char with 0xFF when converting narrow string to wide string?

Tags: c++, c++11, wstring

Consider this function to [convert narrow strings to wide strings](/a/39018368):

```
std::wstring convert(const std::string& input)
{
    try
    {
        std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
        return converter.from_bytes(input);
    }
    catch(std::range_error& e)
    {
        std::size_t length = input.length();
        std::wstring result;
        result.reserve(length);
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            result.push_back(input[i] & 0xFF);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I am having difficulty understanding the need for this expression in the fallback path:

```
result.push_back(input[i] & 0xFF);
```

Why is each character in the string being masked with 0xFF (0b11111111)?

Comment: Why are you asking other people here, instead of the person who wrote that code sample? We have comments for that. I don't see how using a separate question instead makes sense or is useful.

Comment: That looks like it converts any value higher than the highest ASCII value to an acceptable ASCII value.

Comment: @ underscore_d that was written in 2016. So I was not sure if it would get answered

Comment: And yet its author logged on just 2 days ago, as shown in their profile, so I don't see why you'd be unable to get a reply from them.

Comment: The point is I would like to know why a character would be ANDed to a byte

Comment: `0xFF` is an **integer literal**, not a "byte" (which isn't even a thing in C++).

Comment: @TobySpeight C++17 added `std::byte`...

Comment: Thanks @underscore_d, I forgot that.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is on systems where `whar_t` is **signed**. By explicitly making `char` an `int` in that way prevents *sign extension* which would corrupt the value.

Comment: MistyD, underscore_d: First, posing a follow-up question as separate question seems totally right to me. I am the requested writer of that code snippet. To answer the question, I don’t know any more because I am out of C++ for ages now again, but it seems to me that the below answer from Toby Speight is exactly correct. Short answer: It didn’t work without and I must have found this somewhere and it solved it. By the way, I was using Visual Studio with its compiler (default settings, I think), so maybe it is a problem only happening on Windows I was fixing here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Masking with `0xFF` reduces any negative values into the range 0-255.

This is reasonable if, for example, your platform's `char` is an 8-bit signed type representing ISO-8859-1 characters, and your `wchar_t` is representing UCS-2, UTF-16 or UCS-4.

---

Without this correction (or something similar, such as casting to `unsigned char` or `std::byte`), you would find that characters are sign-extended when promoted to the wider type.

Example: 0xa9 (`©` in Unicode and Latin-1, -87 in signed 8-bit) would become `\uffa9` instead of `\u00a9`.

---

I think it's clearer to convert the `char` to an `unsigned char` - that works for any size char, and conveys the intent better.  You can change that expression directly, or create a `codecvt` subclass that gives a name to what you're doing.

Here's how to write and use a minimal `codecvt` (for narrow → wide conversion only):

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

class codecvt_latin1 : public std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,std::mbstate_t>
{
protected:
    virtual result do_in(std::mbstate_t&,
                         const char* from,
                         const char* from_end,
                         const char*& from_next,
                         wchar_t* to,
                         wchar_t* to_end,
                         wchar_t*& to_next) const override
    {
        while (from != from_end && to != to_end)
            *to++ = (unsigned char)*from++;
        from_next = from;
        to_next = to;
        return result::ok;
    }
};

std::wstring convert(const std::string& input)
{
    using codecvt_utf8 = std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>;
    try {
        return std::wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8>().from_bytes(input);
    } catch (std::range_error&) {
        return std::wstring_convert<codecvt_latin1>{}.from_bytes(input);
    }
}
```

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale{""});

    // UTF-8:  £© おはよう
    std::wcout << convert(u8"\xc2\xa3\xc2\xa9 おはよう") << std::endl;
    // Latin-1: Â£©
    std::wcout << convert("\xc2\xa3\xa9") << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
£© おはよう
Â£©
```

Comment: I might be missing something here but 0xa9 is 169 decimal (unsigned) . How is this signed again ?

Comment: @MistyD On some systems both `char` and `wchar_t` are *signed*.

Comment: If `char` is a **signed type** and if `CHAR_BIT` is **8**, then the range of `char` is -128 to +127 (i.e. the same as a `std::int8_t`).  If you store 169 into a `std::int8_t`, that's greater than +127, so it will be truncated to -87.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like on conversion failure the code tries its own conversion by just copying the `string` into a `wstring` char for char.

The `& 0FF` is meant to "clean" any values higher than 255 to fit in the (extended) ASCII table. This is a no-op however because `input[i]` returns `char` and `sizeof(char) == 1` which would mean that 255 is the maximum value anyway (In the case of `CHAR_BIT == 8` and `char == unsigned char`).

The equivalent would just be to copy them over right away using the constructor:

```
std::wstring result(input.begin(), input.end());
```

Comment: so are you saying using `std::wstring result(input.begin(), input.end());` in the catch statement would have the similar effect ?

Comment: @MistyD Yes. it would.

Comment: Actually I get different results if I pass in '\xc2'

Comment: isnt char always 8 bit ?

Comment: If it was **ASCII**, then the constant would need to be `0x7F` - ASCII is a 7-bit code.

Comment: @MistyD - the standard impose that a `char` is 8 bit or more.

Comment: @TobySpeight There we go. I know The C++-goers here like the details :P. Thanks for the help and the spelling corrections.

Comment: @TobySpeight in that case why would I get different results if I pass in  '\xc2' which is unicode for copyright symbol.

Comment: @Misty: Probably because your platform's `char` is a signed type - when promoted to `std::wchar_t` (in the `push_back()`), the value will be sign-extended.

Comment: Can you explain that a little bit more in the answer ? I understand `wstring` uses `wchar_t` so not sure how that makes a difference

Comment: @Misty, Unicode `\xc2` is `Â`, not a copyright symbol.  (It does happen to be the first octet of a UTF-8 encoding of `©`, but that's not at all the same).

Comment: Sorry I meant `\xa9`

Comment: This won't necessarily be a no-op on systems with *signed* `wchar_t` types which could have their negative bit set by higher values (*sign extension*).