# Unable to work with utf8 character in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;
int main(){
    string str = "∑カ[キ…クケコ°サシÀスセÏÔÎソタ]—チツテトÃナニヌÊネノЖИѠѬѰѪᐂᑧᐫᐑᕓᕩᘷᙈᏍsᏜᎹ᳐盘的";
    cout << "--> String: " << str << endl;
    cout<<"--> Size str1: "<<str.size()<<endl;   
    
    for(unsigned ii=0; ii<=str.size();++ii)
    { 
        cout <<"--> ii: "<<ii<< " --> Character: "<< str[ii] <<endl;
    }
}
```

I'm using the ConEmu console with chcp 65001 setting (utf8), everything works fine when displaying the string `str`.

But when I'm trying to use each individual character of the string `str` and displaying I got a wrong display.

Can anybody tell me how to work with individual character?

Comment: Try to use `wcout` and `wstring`, and add prefix `L` before string literal?

Comment: @JohnDing Please absolutely don’t. `std::wstring` should be relegated to history and never touched except to interface with legacy API.

Comment: @KonradRudolph ahh, i just want to give a quick fix in the comment section. I know using `u16_string` and `u32_string` will be better. However it's hard to find suitable IO operations for them. As for `u8_string`, I don't think C++20 is an option.

Comment: Also, `for(unsigned ii=0; ii<=str.size();++ii)`  out of bounds.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Of course, your suggestion is absolutely correct.

Comment: @JohnDing that won't help! On Windows it's UTF-16 so you can't print characters outside the BMP if you print the individual code units

Answer (score 1):

[UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) uses between 1 and 4 bytes to encode a single character.

So you can decode it by reading as many bytes as needed based on the value of the first byte:

- `0xxxxxxx` - 1 byte
- `110xxxxx` - 2 bytes
- `1110xxxx` - 3 bytes
- `11110xxx` - 4 bytes

(notice some gaps between these values - those are invalid UTF-8 values)

For example like this:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    string str = "∑カ[キ…クケコ°サシÀスセÏÔÎソタ]—チツテトÃナニヌÊネノЖИѠѬѰѪᐂᑧᐫᐑᕓᕩᘷᙈᏍsᏜᎹ᳐盘的";
    cout << "--> String: " << str << endl;
    cout << "--> Size str1: " << str.size() << endl;

    string buf;
    int i = 0, count = 0;
    for (unsigned char c : str)
    {
        if (count == 0) {
            buf = c;
            if (c >= 0xF0)
                count = 3;
            else if (c >= 0xE0)
                count = 2;
            else if (c >= 0xC0)
                count = 1;
        } else {
            buf += c;
            --count;
        }
        if (count > 0)
            continue;
        cout << "--> ii: " << i++ << " --> Character: " << buf;
        cout << "  UTF-8 bytes:";
        for (unsigned char b : buf) {
            cout << " " << uppercase << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << (int)b;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
--> String: ∑カ[キ…クケコ°サシÀスセÏÔÎソタ]—チツテトÃナニヌÊネノЖИѠѬѰѪᐂᑧᐫᐑᕓᕩᘷᙈᏍsᏜᎹ᳐盘的
--> Size str1: 140
--> ii: 0 --> Character: ∑  UTF-8 bytes: E2 88 91
--> ii: 1 --> Character: カ  UTF-8 bytes: E3 82 AB
--> ii: 2 --> Character: [  UTF-8 bytes: 5B
--> ii: 3 --> Character: キ  UTF-8 bytes: E3 82 AD
--> ii: 4 --> Character: …  UTF-8 bytes: E2 80 A6
--> ii: 5 --> Character: ク  UTF-8 bytes: E3 82 AF
--> ii: 6 --> Character: ケ  UTF-8 bytes: E3 82 B1
--> ii: 7 --> Character: コ  UTF-8 bytes: E3 82 B3
--> ii: 8 --> Character: °  UTF-8 bytes: C2 B0
--> ii: 9 --> Character: サ  UTF-8 bytes: E3 82 B5
--> ii: A --> Character: シ  UTF-8 bytes: E3 82 B7
--> ii: B --> Character: À  UTF-8 bytes: C3 80
--> ii: C --> Character: ス  UTF-8 bytes: E3 82 B9
--> ii: D --> Character: セ  UTF-8 bytes: E3 82 BB
--> ii: E --> Character: Ï  UTF-8 bytes: C3 8F
--> ii: F --> Character: Ô  UTF-8 bytes: C3 94
--> ii: 10 --> Character: Î  UTF-8 bytes: C3 8E
--> ii: 11 --> Character: ソ  UTF-8 bytes: E3 82 BD
--> ii: 12 --> Character: タ  UTF-8 bytes: E3 82 BF
--> ii: 13 --> Character: ]  UTF-8 bytes: 5D
--> ii: 14 --> Character: —  UTF-8 bytes: E2 80 94
--> ii: 15 --> Character: チ  UTF-8 bytes: E3 83 81
--> ii: 16 --> Character: ツ  UTF-8 bytes: E3 83 84
--> ii: 17 --> Character: テ  UTF-8 bytes: E3 83 86
--> ii: 18 --> Character: ト  UTF-8 bytes: E3 83 88
--> ii: 19 --> Character: Ã  UTF-8 bytes: C3 83
--> ii: 1A --> Character: ナ  UTF-8 bytes: E3 83 8A
--> ii: 1B --> Character: ニ  UTF-8 bytes: E3 83 8B
--> ii: 1C --> Character: ヌ  UTF-8 bytes: E3 83 8C
--> ii: 1D --> Character: Ê  UTF-8 bytes: C3 8A
--> ii: 1E --> Character: ネ  UTF-8 bytes: E3 83 8D
--> ii: 1F --> Character: ノ  UTF-8 bytes: E3 83 8E
--> ii: 20 --> Character: Ж  UTF-8 bytes: D0 96
--> ii: 21 --> Character: И  UTF-8 bytes: D0 98
--> ii: 22 --> Character: Ѡ  UTF-8 bytes: D1 A0
--> ii: 23 --> Character: Ѭ  UTF-8 bytes: D1 AC
--> ii: 24 --> Character: Ѱ  UTF-8 bytes: D1 B0
--> ii: 25 --> Character: Ѫ  UTF-8 bytes: D1 AA
--> ii: 26 --> Character: ᐂ  UTF-8 bytes: E1 90 82
--> ii: 27 --> Character: ᑧ  UTF-8 bytes: E1 91 A7
--> ii: 28 --> Character: ᐫ  UTF-8 bytes: E1 90 AB
--> ii: 29 --> Character: ᐑ  UTF-8 bytes: E1 90 91
--> ii: 2A --> Character: ᕓ  UTF-8 bytes: E1 95 93
--> ii: 2B --> Character: ᕩ  UTF-8 bytes: E1 95 A9
--> ii: 2C --> Character: ᘷ  UTF-8 bytes: E1 98 B7
--> ii: 2D --> Character: ᙈ  UTF-8 bytes: E1 99 88
--> ii: 2E --> Character: Ꮝ  UTF-8 bytes: E1 8F 8D
--> ii: 2F --> Character: s  UTF-8 bytes: 73
--> ii: 30 --> Character: Ꮬ  UTF-8 bytes: E1 8F 9C
--> ii: 31 --> Character: Ꮉ  UTF-8 bytes: E1 8E B9
--> ii: 32 --> Character: ᳐  UTF-8 bytes: E1 B3 90
--> ii: 33 --> Character: 盘  UTF-8 bytes: E7 9B 98
--> ii: 34 --> Character: 的  UTF-8 bytes: E7 9A 84
```

As you can see, each UTF-8 code point in the string is encoded using 1, 2 or 3 bytes (note that the `char` data type usually contains just 1 byte).

This can be inconvenient if you want to work with individual Unicode symbols as a unit. In this case you can convert the string to a `wstring` and work with wide-char type (`wchar_t`) instead of `char`.

See the following link to the question about [how to convert a `string` to a `wstring`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573834/c-convert-string-or-char-to-wstring-or-wchar-t).

Comment: It's working for display, but do you think it will work by using the find method ? like finding a character in the str ?

Comment: Yes, you can search for a substring consisting of bytes of a single Unicode code point. This works because UTF-8 is self-synchronizing i.e. it's impossible to find a code point at the middle of another code point. What you cannot do is select Unicode characters randomly by offset, you can only do that sequentially since the position of a UTF-8 character depends on the size of all previous characters in the string.

Comment: Thks. But still do not understand why when using "shuffle (str.begin(), str.end(), default_random_engine(seed));." and display the str after I have a wrong display ? Isthe byte value is affected by the shuffle ?

Comment: A UTF-8 encoded symbol consists of multiple bytes. shuffle breaks that because it moves individual bytes around. See my updated answer for more details.

Comment: Thks rustyx. Does that mean c++ is not able to manipulate Unicode easily ? Python 3.4 is doing it

Comment: rustyx: If I understood well your solution, I have to isolate and work with substring at bytes level of each character ? If so, it's very complicated.

Comment: Yes, C++ is much more low-level than Python and requires full understanding of how strings are represented in memory. But as I said, consider trying out `wstring`, it can simplify working with Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anybody tell me how to work with individual character ?

By following the Unicode specification.

Individual `char` objects in C++ correspond to a code unit of unicode. Interleaving other code units in between separate code units of a single character will break the encoding.

There is no standard C++ function to iterate unicode characters.

Comment: Note that C++20 has a `char8_t` type now. It doesn't help in any way other than the fact that it is always unsigned by default (in all compilers) which makes it a little easier to work with than `char`. But since all existing functions expect `char`... it's not what I'd call practical.

Answer (score 0):

rustyx as the right answer, presenting how UTF-8 characters are encoded.

This is definitely not trivial, however, if you use a library, it can become pretty easy to work with UTF-8. You just have to remember that most characters are not encoded using 8 bits (actually, only 128 characters fit inside 8 bits, all the others use 2 to 4 bytes, for a total of 1,112,064¹ possible characters).

Note that the UTF-8 encoding scheme actually supports 1 to 7 bytes, but the Unicode characters are limited to a number between 0 and 0x10FFFF inclusive. This is why only 4 bytes are required. (In the old days, there was no such restrictions.)

So on my end, I wrote the [libutf8 library](https://github.com/m2osw/libutf8), which has the ability to convert UTF-8 to UTF-16 and UTF-32 and vice versa. It also includes [an iterator](https://github.com/m2osw/libutf8/blob/main/libutf8/iterator.cpp) allowing you to iterate through a UTF-8 string one character at a time. You can read the character as a `char32_t` value which supports any Unicode character.

Here is an example:

```
std::string s = "some string...";

for(libutf8::utf8_iterator it(s); it != s.end(); ++it)
{
    char32_t c(*it);

    // here you can choose:
    if(c == libutf8::NOT_A_CHARACTER)
    {
        // handle error -- current character is not valid UTF-8
        break;
    }
    // -- or --
    if(it.bad())
    {
        // handle error -- current character is not valid UTF-8
        break;
    }

    // 'c' is valid, you can print it, etc.
    ...
}
```

I also offer a reverse iterator.

The library also has other functions such as the `u8length()` to compute the length of the UTF-8 string in characters (instead of the `strlen()` which counts the bytes).

***Note 1:** Since C++20, the compiler includes the `char8_t` type. This is distinct from the `char` type. It is always `unsigned` by default (contrary to `char` which some compiler view as `signed` by default) but it is otherwise just a byte. In other words, it still requires you to know how to encode/decode UTF-8 properly.*

***Note 2:** The C library offers many of these functions, which work with any type of multi-byte encoding... meaning that if your console (locale) is not set to UTF-8, you are likely to not get the correct results. This is why I'd rather have my own library and use that and not rely on a parameter the user can easily mess up. See for example `mblen(3)`, `mbrtowc(3)`, `wcstombs(3)`, etc.*

---

¹ *The number 1,112,064 comes from (0x110000 - 0x800). The 0x800 comes from the UTF-16 surrogates, code bytes 0xD800 to 0xDFFF. The surrogates are only valid in UTF-16 and are used to encode characters from 0x10000 to 0x10FFFF. These code bytes are invalid in UTF-8 and UTF-32. Note further that all characters that end with 0xXXFFFE and 0xXXFFFF are not considered valid either. However, they can safely be encoded in UTF-8 and UTF-32.*