# C++ "stock ticker" with UTF-8 strings

Tags: c++, utf-8, stdstring

A part of the project includes something similar to a scrolling 'stock ticker', where a larger string "scrolls across" a fixed width output string.

Using C++ 11 on Linux, the concept is clear when using latin characters. Something like this:

```
std::string inputString, outputString;
for (int inIdx = 0; inIdx < inputString.size(); inIdx++)
{
    // shift output one character left
    for (int i = 0; i < mOutputTextWidth - 1; i++)
        outputString[i] = outputString[i+1];

    // Append character to end of output
    if (inIdx < inputString.size())
        outputString[mTextWidth] = inputString.at(inIdx);
    sleep(1);
}
```

You would get something like:

```
[           ]
[          H]
[         HE]
[        HEL]
[      HELLO]
[     HELLO ]
[    HELLO  ]
[   HELLO   ]
```

I need to make this work for UTF-8 non-latin characters.  From what I've read, it is a complex subject. In particular `std::string::at` or `[]` returns a char, which breaks on long UTF-8 characters.

In C++ what's the right way of doing this?

Eg. Japanese

```
[              ]
[            こ]
[          こん]
[        こんば]
[      こんばん]
[    こんばんは]
[  こんばんは  ]
[ こんばんは   ]
```

(I know the glyph widths will vary by language, that's ok.  I just can't figure out how to manipulate UTF-8 strings)

Comment: I recently posted an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60975518/unable-to-work-with-utf8-character-in-c). It may be useful in understanding how UTF-8 is represented in memory.

Comment: UTF-8 support in standard C++ is sketchy. The best course of action heavily depends on your platform and toolset. If you want portable code, you probably want to use a third party library.

Comment: Moreover, if you want minimally competent Unicode support, you have no choice but to use a third party library. C++ has no facilities to determine screen width of a string, or to inspect whether a given character is a regular, zero-width, double-width, or combining one.

Comment: n. 'pronouns' m: Do you have some suggestions for a third party library?

Answer (score 0):

On systems that support Unicode natively (which includes Linux)<sup>1</sup>, you can simply use the standard [C++ multibyte support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte) and work with [`wchar_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Character_types) types to handle one unicode code point at a time.

For example like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <clocale>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string inputUTF8 = "こんばんは！"; // assuming this source is stored in UTF-8

    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8"); // tell mbstowcs use want UTF-8->wchar_t conversion
    std::wcout.imbue(std::locale("en_US.utf8")); // tell std::wcout we want wchar_t->UTF-8 output

    std::vector<wchar_t> buf(inputUTF8.size() + 1); // reserve space
    int len = (int)std::mbstowcs(buf.data(), inputUTF8.c_str(), buf.size()); // convert to wchar_t
    if (len == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Invalid UTF-8 input\n"; // mbstowcs can fail
        return 1;
    }
    std::wstring out;
    for (int i = 0; i < len * 2; i++)
    {
        out.assign(std::max(0, len - i), L'　'); // fill with ideographic space (U+3000) before

        out.append(buf.data(), std::max(0, i - len), std::min(len, i) - std::max(0, i - len));

        out.append(std::max(0, i - len), L'　'); // fill with ideographic space after

        std::wcout << L"[" << out << L"]\n";
    }
}
```

[Output](https://rextester.com/LKPJ3876):

```
[　　　　　　]
[　　　　　こ]
[　　　　こん]
[　　　こんば]
[　　こんばん]
[　こんばんは]
[こんばんは！]
[んばんは！　]
[ばんは！　　]
[んは！　　　]
[は！　　　　]
[！　　　　　]
```

Beware that `mbstowcs` and other locale stuff is not thread-safe.

Another possibility is to use a library like [iconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/).

---

<sup>1</sup> Unfortunately on [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_in_Microsoft_Windows) Unicode support is crippled; it's `wchar_t` is 16 bits long and actually represents UTF-16, as such the program will work for the [basic plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) code points only (which still includes the typical CJK symbols, but not unified Han or other symbols above U+FFFF). Though that can still be fixed by taking UTF-16 into account.

Answer (score 0):

After the numerous warnings against `wchar` I implemented a solution based on the comment referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60975518/unable-to-work-with-utf8-character-in-c) from [rustyx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485343/rustyx).  There might be holes in this approach but so far works for me when tested with English/latin and Japanese input.

(I believe the code below works only with UTF-8, not sure about other legacy encodings like EUC-JP, SHIFT_JIS, etc)

Note that `symbolLength()` identifies the number of code points present and which will not be the same as the screen width since differing widths (or zero width!) code points might be present.

```
TqString::TqString(const std::string &s) { assign(s); }

TqString::TqString(const char *cs)
{
    std::string s(cs);
    assign(s);
}

TqString::TqString(size_t n, char c)
{
    std::string s(n, c);
    assign(s);
}

TqString &TqString::operator=(const std::string &s)
{
    assign(s);
    return *this;
}

// Unlike size(), this returns the number of UTF-8 code points
// in the input string

size_t
TqString::symbolLength() const
{
    int  symCount = 0;
    int skipCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
    {
        unsigned char c = at(i);
        if (skipCount == 0)
        {
            if (c >= 0xF0)
                skipCount = 3;
            else if (c >= 0xE0)
                skipCount = 2;
            else if (c >= 0xC0)
                skipCount = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            --skipCount;
        }

        if (skipCount > 0)
            continue;

        symCount++;
    }
    return symCount;
}

// Scan input string, skipping over 'n' symbols, and returning the last

std::string
TqString::symbolAt(off_t n) const
{
    std::string outString;
    int skipCount = 0;
    int symCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
    {
        unsigned char c = at(i);
        if (skipCount == 0)
        {
            outString = c;
            if (c >= 0xF0)
                skipCount = 3;
            else if (c >= 0xE0)
                skipCount = 2;
            else if (c >= 0xC0)
                skipCount = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            outString += c;
            --skipCount;
        }

        if (skipCount > 0)
            continue;


        if (symCount == n)
            break;

        symCount++;
    }

    return outString;
}

void
TqString::shiftLeft()
{
    std::string outString;
    if (size() == 0)
    {
        assign(outString);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < symbolLength(); i++)
    {
        outString += symbolAt(i);
    }

    assign(outString);
}

// shift then append 's' to the end
void
TqString::shiftLeft(const TqString &s)
{
    shiftLeft();
    append(s);
}

std::string
TqString::str() const
{
    std::string ret(data());
    return ret;
}
```