# Enabling UNICODE in gcc windows api string processing

Tags: c++, mingw-w64, winmm

I am trying scan thru windows wave devices, using following test snippet in `test.cpp`;

```cpp
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>

int main () 
{ 
    int nDeviceCount = waveOutGetNumDevs();
    vector<wstring> sDevices;
    WAVEOUTCAPS woc;
    for (int n = 0; n < nDeviceCount; n++)
        if (waveOutGetDevCaps(n, &woc, sizeof(WAVEOUTCAPS)) == S_OK) {
            wstring dvc(woc.szPname);
            sDevices.push_back(dvc);
        }
    return 0; 
}
```

Compiled in PowerShell with `gcc version 8.1.0 (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)`, I get this error:

```
PS xxx> g++ .\test.cpp -c
.\test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
.\test.cpp:14:27: error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t>::basic_string(CHAR [32])'
    wstring dvc(woc.szPname);
```

I thought `wstring` constructor includes support for c-style null-terminated strings. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573834/c-convert-string-or-char-to-wstring-or-wchar-t) is about converting `string` to `wstring` but the answers are still applicable.

Comment: And if your code page is not the UTF-8 one, you will have to properly convert string to the proper encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `UNICODE` macro is undefined. This makes the `pzPname` field be `CHAR pzPname[MAXPNAMELEN]` in the definition. That’s why the error arises, as the `std::wstring` is trying to initialize with `char` data rather than `wchar_t` data.

To resolve this, place a `#define UNICODE` statement before including the `Windows.h` file, or use `std::string` instead.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. defining ``UNICODE`` solved the issue.

Comment: Or, you can simply forget about `UNICODE` and use `waveOutDevCapsW()`/`WAVEOUTCAPSW` directly instead.