# Why cannot I convert a string with an en dash into a wstring?

Tags: c++, string, unicode, utf-8

The following code fails and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
std::string s = "–";
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
std::wstring wide = converter.from_bytes(s);
```

I tried reading up on UTF-8, but I couldn't figure it out. Storing the initial string as a wstring, converting it to a string then converting it back gives the correct result.

```
std::wstring ws = L"–";
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
std::string narrow = converter.to_bytes(ws);
std::wstring wide = converter.from_bytes(narrow);
```

Comment: the issue seems to happen with all the extended ascii characters after 128

Comment: I have taken code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18597384/6368600, according to which it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, your C++ source file is not saved as UTF-8, or the compiler is not interpreting it as UTF-8, either way causing `"–"` to not actually represent `U+2013 EN DASH` at runtime.  You can easily verify that at runtime, such as with a debugger, or just printing out the raw bytes of your `string`.

Make sure your C++ file is saved in UTF-8, and compiled as UTF-8.  Or else try using this code instead:

```cpp
std::string s = u8"–";
```

Or:

```cpp
std::string s = "\xE2\x80\x93";
```