# Move a file or folder to the RecycleBin/Trash (C++17)

Tags: c++, winapi, c++17

I am trying to write function to move files to trash.
For example when I use a file path with unicode and whitespace I cannot send it to the Recycle Bin.

```
...\Yönü Değiştir\Yönü Değiştir Sil.txt
```

I found many examples on the forum.
But I couldn't run it correctly.

Where did I go wrong,
Can you help me write the function correctly?

My function and code is like this:

```
. includes...
.
.
    bool recycle_file_folder(std::string path) {
    
        std::wstring widestr = std::wstring(path.begin(), path.end());
        const wchar_t* widecstr = widestr.c_str();
    
        SHFILEOPSTRUCT fileOp; //#include <Windows.h>;        
        fileOp.hwnd = NULL;       
        fileOp.wFunc = FO_DELETE;        
        fileOp.pFrom = widecstr; /// L"C:\\Users\\USER000\\Documents\\Yönü Değiştir\\Yönü Değiştir Sil.txt";
        fileOp.pTo = NULL;        
        fileOp.fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_SILENT;
        int result = SHFileOperation(&fileOp);
        
        if (result != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

int main()
{
   std::filesystem::path p("C:\\Users\\USER000\\Documents\\Yönü Değiştir\\Yönü Değiştir Sil.txt");

   recycle_file_folder(p.string());

   return 0;
}
```

Now it works successfully when you specify the file like this:

```
fileOp.pFrom = L"C:\\Users\\USER000\\Documents\\Yönü Değiştir\\Yönü Değiştir Sil.txt";
```

How do I adapt this to function for all files?

Comment: `return result == 0;` smh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Convert string (or char\*) to wstring (or wchar\_t\*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573834/c-convert-string-or-char-to-wstring-or-wchar-t)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your conversion between wstring and string has problem. Note that std::filesystem supports converting to both string and wstring so let's re-write your code a bit

```
bool recycle_file_folder(std::wstring path) {

    std::wstring widestr = path + std::wstring(1, L'\0');

    SHFILEOPSTRUCT fileOp;      
    fileOp.hwnd = NULL;       
    fileOp.wFunc = FO_DELETE;        
    fileOp.pFrom = widestr.c_str();
    fileOp.pTo = NULL;        
    fileOp.fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_SILENT;
    int result = SHFileOperation(&fileOp);
    
    if (result != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

int main()
{
   std::filesystem::path p("C:\\Users\\USER000\\Documents\\Yönü Değiştir\\Yönü Değiştir Sil.txt");

   recycle_file_folder(p.wstring());

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: `std::wstring` has an `operator+` that appends a single `wchar_t`, eg: `std::wstring widestr = path + L'\0';`

Comment: With this function I have success with files but I get an error in folders even though they are moved to trash. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

> a file path with unicode and whitespace

The problem is not in whitespace, it is with non-ASCII characters.

> ```
> std::wstring widestr = std::wstring(path.begin(), path.end());
> ```

This is not a correct way to convert characters of some code page to UTF-16.
You'll have to use a method suggested in this Q&A: [C++ Convert string (or char*) to wstring (or wchar_t*)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2573834/2945027) (Ignore the answer by Pietro M, look into other answers)

Alternately, use `SHFileOperationA`, and `SHFILEOPSTRUCTA`, but it is a worse solution.

Comment: The OP's code is also not **double**-null-terminating the string passed to `fileOp.pFrom`