# Read whole ASCII file into C++ std::string

Tags: c++, string, caching, file-io, standard-library

I need to read a whole file into memory and place it in a C++ `std::string`.

If I were to read it into a `char[]`, the answer would be very simple:

```
std::ifstream t;
int length;
t.open("file.txt");      // open input file
t.seekg(0, std::ios::end);    // go to the end
length = t.tellg();           // report location (this is the length)
t.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);    // go back to the beginning
buffer = new char[length];    // allocate memory for a buffer of appropriate dimension
t.read(buffer, length);       // read the whole file into the buffer
t.close();                    // close file handle

// ... Do stuff with buffer here ...
```

Now, I want to do the exact same thing, but using a `std::string` instead of a `char[]`. I want to avoid loops, i.e. I **don't** want to:

```
std::ifstream t;
t.open("file.txt");
std::string buffer;
std::string line;
while(t){
std::getline(t, line);
// ... Append line to buffer and go on
}
t.close()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There will always be a loop involved, but it can be implicit as part of the standard library.  Is that acceptable?  Why are you trying to avoid loops?

Comment: I believe that the poster knew that reading bytes involved looping. He just wanted an easy, perl-style *gulp* equivalent. That involved writing little code.

Comment: This code is buggy, in the event that the std::string doesn't use a continuous buffer for its string data (which is allowed): http://stackoverflow.com/a/1043318/1602642

Comment: @ChrisDesjardins: (1) Your link is outdated (C++11 made it contiguous) and (2) even if it wasn't, `std::getline(istream&, std::string&)` would still do the right thing.

Comment: Side note for anyone looking at this code: The code presented as an example for reading into char[] does not null-terminate the array (read does not do this automatically), which may not be what you expect.

Comment: "the answer would be very simple".  Understandable yes, simple no ;-)

Comment: Casting the `streampos` returned by `tellg()` into an `int` is not guaranteed to return the length of the file. If you subtract the `streampos` at the start of the file from that at the end of the file, you will get a `streamoff` which is guaranteed to be of an integral type and represent an offset in the file, at least in C++11. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/streamoff/ and the comment in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10135341/1908650. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2409527/1908650 for a safe version.

Comment: Why is this question closed for answers as it is super outdated and needs new answers? Plus it has more than 650 upvotes.. beyond me

Comment: @AdanVivero It's closed as a duplicate. New answers should be posted on the linked question.

Answer (score 614, accepted):

**Update:** Turns out that this method, while following STL idioms well, is actually surprisingly inefficient! Don't do this with large files. (See: http://insanecoding.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-read-in-file-in-c.html)

You can make a streambuf iterator out of the file and initialize the string with it:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>

std::ifstream t("file.txt");
std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Not sure where you're getting the `t.open("file.txt", "r")` syntax from. As far as I know that's not a method that `std::ifstream` has. It looks like you've confused it with C's `fopen`.

**Edit:** Also note the extra parentheses around the first argument to the string constructor. *These are essential*. They prevent the problem known as the "[most vexing parse](http://web.archive.org/web/20110426155617/http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=439)", which in this case won't actually give you a compile error like it usually does, but will give you interesting (read: wrong) results.

Following KeithB's point in the comments, here's a way to do it that allocates all the memory up front (rather than relying on the string class's automatic reallocation):

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>

std::ifstream t("file.txt");
std::string str;

t.seekg(0, std::ios::end);   
str.reserve(t.tellg());
t.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

str.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Comment: open is definitely a method of ifstream, however the 2nd parameter is wrong.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/open/

Comment: Right. I was saying that `ifstream` doesn't have a method with the signature `open(const char*, const char*)`

Comment: This is just making the explicit loop implicit. Since the iterator is a forward iterator, it will be read one character at a time.  Also, since there is no way for the string constructor to know the final length, it will probably lead to several allocations and copies of the data.

Comment: Yep, I am starting off with C++ and I'm still quite illiterate. Thanks for the answer, though, it is exactly what I needed. +1.

Comment: no second parameter is required - ifstreams are input streams

Comment: @KeithB If efficiency is important, you could find the file length the same was as in the `char*` example and call `std::string::reserve` to preallocate the necessary space.

Comment: @KeithB:  Of course, the `read()` method undoubtedly has lots of looping going on.  The question is not whether it loops but where and how explicitly.

Comment: In the `str.assign()` approach the first argument's parentheses are unnecessary, because it can't parse as a declaration.

Comment: Note that the file may be longer than the string.  If your OS uses <CR><LF> (two `char`s) as a line separator, the string will use '\n' (one `char`).  Text streams do conversions to and from '\n' to the underlying representation.

Comment: @Adrian `'\n'` is merely a portable way of specifying newline in C code. Down below the compiler will still translate `'\n'` to what's appropriate for a newline for the compiler's operating system.

Comment: No sure why people are voting this up, here is a quick question, say I have a 1MB file, how many times will the "end" passed to the std::string constructor or assign method be invoked? People think these kind of solutions are elegant when in fact they are excellent examples of HOW NOT TO DO IT.

Comment: @Matthieu N. You're going to have to explain that a little more, it looks like once to me.

Comment: @MaxEhrlich he probably means dereferencing. for a 1MB file this would require about 1M compares, which doesn't seem really efficient.

Comment: Benchmarked: both Tyler's solutions take about 21 seconds on a 267 MB file. Jerry's first takes 1.2 seconds and his second 0.5 (+/- 0.1), so clearly there's something inefficient about Tyler's code.

Comment: @dhardy You're right. About a year after I wrote this post, somebody did some benchmarking of various approaches to this problem and found that reserve+assign unfortunately does not seem to work the way that you would hope it did. And it turns out that in general iterators produce a surprisng amount of overhead. Disappointing. Edited this into the post.

Comment: The insanecoding blog post is benchmarking solutions to a slightly different problem: it is reading the file as binary not text, so there's no translation of line endings. As a side effect, reading as binary makes ftell a reliable way to get the file length (assuming a long can represent the file length, which is not guaranteed). For determining the length, ftell is not reliable on a text stream. If you're reading a file from tape (e.g., a backup), the extra seeking may be a waste of time. Many of the blog post implementations don't use RAII and can therefore leak if there's an error.

Comment: Luke, use **std::ios::ate** 
  `std::ifstream t("file.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
         str.reserve(t.tellg());`

Comment: While this answer is highly ranked, with the updates and edits stating that the method is slow now it's a mess. Do you have a method that is using stl facilities that is also fast? If so, clean all the mess and just write it in a concise way.

Comment: yep,this answer is quite messy. In particular: does the update ("dont do this with large files") refer to the first code? what exactly is the inefficiency? does the second code fix it?

Comment: With C++17 you can shorten the `std::string` initialization line quite nicely (and similarly for the `str.assign` method): `std::string str{std::istreambuf_iterator{in}, {}};`. This uses C++11 brace initialization syntax and C++17 deduction guides (to omit the `<char>`).

Comment: Well, I used this solution and I found that it will stop at the first null char when I read a file that contains null char paddings. That's really annoying. It should be better just to use t.read(buffer_.c_str(), size)".

Comment: @Tyler McHenry You said "reserve+assign unfortunately does not seem to work the way that you would hope it did". Does this mean that the reserved memory is discarded and the string is reallocated at its default size when assign is called with iterators? If so, why not use std::copy, from the streambuf_iterators, to a std::back_inserter on the string? std::copy would just use push_back on the string, via the std::back_inserter, so there's no way reserved string memory would shrink this way.

Comment: It would remove the string reallocations throughout the read, which I think would be the majority of the performance slowdown with this method. Iterator overhead I think would just be an extra function call or two per character, which I hope would be inlined with sufficiently aggressive optimization. I may try profiling this...

Comment: He is getting `t.open("file.txt", "r")` from python.

Comment: This gives potential `-Wnull-dereference` warning:  https://godbolt.org/z/KojKWT4WK - not really sure why, the error is hard to read.

Answer (score 1110):

There are a couple of possibilities. One I like uses a stringstream as a go-between:

```
std::ifstream t("file.txt");
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << t.rdbuf();
```

Now the contents of "file.txt" are available in a string as `buffer.str()`.

Another possibility (though I certainly don't like it as well) is much more like your original:

```
std::ifstream t("file.txt");
t.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
size_t size = t.tellg();
std::string buffer(size, ' ');
t.seekg(0);
t.read(&buffer[0], size);
```

Officially, this isn't required to work under the C++98 or 03 standard (string isn't required to store data contiguously) but in fact it works with all known implementations, and C++11 and later do require contiguous storage, so it's guaranteed to work with them.

As to why I don't like the latter as well: first, because it's longer and harder to read. Second, because it requires that you initialize the contents of the string with data you don't care about, then immediately write over that data (yes, the time to initialize is usually trivial compared to the reading, so it probably doesn't matter, but to me it still feels kind of wrong). Third, in a text file, position X in the file doesn't necessarily mean you'll have read X characters to reach that point -- it's not required to take into account things like line-end translations. On real systems that do such translations (e.g., Windows) the translated form is shorter than what's in the file (i.e., "\r\n" in the file becomes "\n" in the translated string) so all you've done is reserved a little extra space you never use. Again, doesn't really cause a major problem but feels a little wrong anyway.

Comment: The three-liner works like a charm!

Comment: This should've been marked as the answer.

Comment: Important note for some, at least on my implementation, the three-liner works at least as good as the C fopen alternative for files under 50KB. Past that, it seems to lose performance fast. In which case, just use the second solution.

Comment: make sure to #include <sstream>

Comment: Should also check to see if the file has opened, e.g., `if (!t) std::cerr << "Error opening file." << std::endl;`. Of course, don't forget to close the file as well when you are done.

Comment: Most of the time, you're fine *not* testing whether the file has opened (the other operations will simply fail). As a rule, you should *avoid* printing out error messages on the spot, unless you're sure that fits with the rest of the program -- if you must do *something*, throwing an exception is usually preferable. You should almost never explicitly close a file either -- the destructor will do that automatically.

Comment: According to my testing (GCC 4.7), the buffer contains the same number of characters as the file size no matter which line endings are used. I'm guessing `read(buf, size)` turns off these conversions — anyone know?

Comment: Where is the data stored in example 2?

Comment: @DissidentRage: Into `buffer`.

Comment: Wouldn't constructing an empty string and then calling `reserve(size)` on it be more efficient?

Comment: If anyone is still interested, the answer to the question of dhardy can be found in the [ifstream doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/): " This function simply copies a block of data, without checking its contents nor appending a null character at the end."

Comment: If you want to get the file as a std::string see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c for a one liner solution.

Comment: fwiw, on OSX 10.10, I needed to #include <fstream> instead of <sstream>

Comment: @anthropomorphic You should not use reserve(), because the size() information is not correctly maintained and the string is in a broken state!

Comment: Can you get the number of chars read in the t.read() call and use that to set the string length.

Comment: @Jasen: Not really--you want to set the length *before* you do the read, so you'll have enough space to read into. By the time you call `read`, it's too late to set the size.

Comment: @duleshi The suggestion was wrong, but your description seems off. One cannot `reserve` then read into the `reserve`d space because no elements exist in the new space. Operations are only valid on elements between `begin` and `begin + size - 1`. The `reserve` only increases `capacity`, beyond `size`. Only the space exists there; elements do not. To create elements, one must use `resize`, `emplace_back`, etc. That's why, if using the 2nd method here, the container must first have its entire `size` declared and all elements default constructed... just so that they can immediately be overwritten.

Comment: OP asked for code to read an ASCII file into a string. Will this read any file, or is there something ASCII-specific lurking under the hood?

Comment: @einpoklum: No. It probably doesn't make much sense to read into a string unless your data is actually a string, but that's not really a limitation, just good sense.

Comment: After puzzling over this for a few minutes (compiler errors -- Windows 10, VS2015), I found I need to include BOTH `#include <sstream>` and `#include <fstream>`. Best of luck!

Comment: @Jasen It is possible to get the total read characters (not bytes/chars!) by using the `std::basic_istream::gcount` function. I believe one should strip of the unused bytes by adding a `buffer.resize(t.gcount());`.

Comment: What are the downsides of combining this into a single line: `(std::stringstream() << std::ifstream("file.txt").rdbuf()).str()` ?

Comment: @AlecJacobson: The primary downside is that it won't compile. If you really want it as a single expression, you *can* do it by adding a cast: `static_cast<std::stringstream &>(std::stringstream() << std::ifstream("file.txt").rdbuf()).str();`. IMO, it's more readable as separate statements though.

Comment: Seems to compile with clang on Mac. Is that just an accident? Why should it not have compiled?

Comment: @AlecJacobson: Because the `operator<<` that takes a pointer to a streambuf returns an `ostream &` --i.e., a pointer to the base object. That's usually fine (for things like chaining), but to use `.str()`, you need a `stringstream` instead. The cast takes the reference to base being returned and casts it back to be a reference to the actual type.

Comment: Your second solution is less elegant, but it is 3 times faster !

Comment: I'm late here too but thought I would comment for those less initiated like myself. The second solution is quite a bit faster and a little less elegant as Pico12 points out. The thing that wasn't absolutely clear to me (and maybe it's just semantics), was what  problems the differences in end line characters might cause. I'm using Codeblocks on win10 with Mingw-w64 GCC. It's not just that you've stored extra space. It's that for every '\n' character, the infile character count is 1 less than what ends up stored in `std::string buffer`. This can cause string nav to be problematic.

Comment: If you want to display the buffer string --> ```std::cout << buffer.str() << std::endl;```

Comment: @JerryCoffin , what are the exceptions you'd have to check against for this?

Comment: brilliant!! i've used in:`string read_file(string file_name) {
  std::stringstream buffer;
  buffer << ifstream(file_name).rdbuf();

  return buffer.str();`
}

Comment: Three-liner is short, but it's confusing. `rdbuf()` returns `filebuf*`. How does putting pointer to `rdbuf` makes `stringstream` to read file content? I would prefer more verbose, but more clear code than this magic.

Comment: Error checking is missing as mentioned by @RaffiKhatchadourian. Whenever you work with files I strongly recommend doing some error handling.

Comment: 3 liner is WRONG, there is no guarantee that entire file fits into buffer, read https://www.reddit.com/r/Cplusplus/comments/6cpekc/what_does_rdbuf_do/dhwedtp?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: The Reddit comment is irrelevant. See §[ostream.inserters]/7: "Gets characters from sb and inserts them in *this. Characters are read from sb and inserted until any of the following occurs: (8.1) — end-of-file occurs on the input sequence; (8.2) — inserting in the output sequence fails (in which case the character to be inserted is not extracted); (8.3) — an exception occurs while getting a character from sb." So, it attempts to copy the remainder of the file controlled by the streambuffer, regardless of how much/little may currently be contained in the streambuffer.

Comment: Strangely I don't obtain the same results with the two variants (I tried with both text or binary open mode) when I read a file from WSL with a shared NFS file system mounted in windows then in linux (via drvfs). I don't know why, but the second variant seems OK while the first one generates some random json parsing issues.

Comment: the size of the 3 lines solution is wrong. buffer.str().size() is wrong!

Comment: Doesn't work if the file is too long/large.

Answer (score 97):

I think best way is to use string stream. simple and quick !!!

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> //std::stringstream
int main() {
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("inFileName"); //open the input file

    std::stringstream strStream;
    strStream << inFile.rdbuf(); //read the file
    std::string str = strStream.str(); //str holds the content of the file

    std::cout << str << "\n"; //you can do anything with the string!!!
}
```

Comment: Simple and quick, right! http://insanecoding.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-read-in-file-in-c.html

Comment: Remember to close the stream afterwards...

Comment: @YngveSneenLindal Or let the destructor do it automatically - take advantage of C++!

Comment: But in Cfree 5, string is not identified as a name type. In that case, will 'char' type work?

Comment: @YngveSneenLindal are you sure you need to close the stream afterwards? Apparently the fstream's memory allocation should be deallocated once fstream is destroyed (out of the scope)? Although it can be good to use `.close()` for error checking?

Comment: you can close stream, if you need. but it is not compulsory. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748014/do-i-need-to-manually-close-an-ifstream

Comment: You're right @DanNissenbaum. Agree!

Comment: Why post this when it was already in the answer by Jerry Coffin from years before?

Answer (score 39):

You may not find this in any book or site, but I found out that it works pretty well:

```
#include <fstream>
// ...
std::string file_content;
std::getline(std::ifstream("filename.txt"), file_content, '\0');
```

Comment: Casting `eof` to `(char)` is a bit dodgy, suggesting some kind of relevance and universality which is illusory.  For some possible values of `eof()` and signed `char`, it will give implementation-defined results.  Directly using e.g. `char(0)` / `'\0'` would be more robust and honestly indicative of what's happening.

Comment: @TonyD. Good point about converting eof() to a char. I suppose for old-school ascii character sets, passing any negative value (msb set to 1) would work. But passing \0 (or a negative value) won't work for wide or multi-byte input files.

Comment: This will only work, as long as there are no "eof" (e.g. 0x00, 0xff, ...) characters in your file. If there are, you will only read part of the file.

Comment: @OlafDietsche There shouldn't be 0x00 in an ASCII file (or I wouldn't call it ASCII file). `0x00` appears to me like a good option to force the `getline()` to read the whole file. And, I must admit that this code is as short as easy to read although the higher voted solutions look much more impressive and sophisticated.

Comment: @Scheff After revisiting this answer, I don't know, how I reached to that conclusion and comment. Maybe I thought, that `(char) ifs.eof()` has some meaning. [`eof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof) returns `false` at this point, and the call is equivalent to `std::getline(ifs, s, 0);`. So it reads until the first 0 byte, or the end of file, if there's no 0 byte.

Comment: Could you please explain how '\0' is a valid delimiter ?

Answer (score 7):

Try one of these two methods:

```
string get_file_string(){
    std::ifstream ifs("path_to_file");
    return string((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),
                  (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
}

string get_file_string2(){
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("path_to_file");//open the input file

    stringstream strStream;
    strStream << inFile.rdbuf();//read the file
    return strStream.str();//str holds the content of the file
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out another way that works with most istreams, including std::cin!

```
std::string readFile()
{
    stringstream str;
    ifstream stream("Hello_World.txt");
    if(stream.is_open())
    {
        while(stream.peek() != EOF)
        {
            str << (char) stream.get();
        }
        stream.close();
        return str.str();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use [glibmm](http://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable) you can try [Glib::file_get_contents](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/group__FileUtils.html#ga835da54212fe78e833ac55b49150b989).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glibmm.h>

int main() {
    auto filename = "my-file.txt";
    try {
        std::string contents = Glib::file_get_contents(filename);
        std::cout << "File data:\n" << contents << std::endl;
    catch (const Glib::FileError& e) {
        std::cout << "Oops, an error occurred:\n" << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Imho: Although this works, providing a "glib" solution, which is the non-platform-independent equivalent of pandora's chest, might confuse enormously, even more, if there's a simple CPP-standard solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

I could do it like this:

```
void readfile(const std::string &filepath,std::string &buffer){
    std::ifstream fin(filepath.c_str());
    getline(fin, buffer, char(-1));
    fin.close();
}
```

If this is something to be frowned upon, please let me know why

Comment: char(-1) is probably not a portable way to denote EOF. Also, getline() implementations are not required to support the "invalid" EOF pseudo-character as a delimiter character, I think.

Comment: @reddish it indeed isn't, in modern C++ it is better to use `std::char_traits<char>::eof()`. If someone is still using an ancient compiler... `<cstdio>` contains `EOF` macro.

Answer (score -6):

I don't think you can do this without an explicit or implicit loop, without reading into a char array (or some other container) first and ten constructing the string.  If you don't need the other capabilities of a string, it could be done with `vector<char>` the same way you are currently using a `char *`.

Comment: -1 Not true... See above

Comment: Well, to be fair, all of the answers above do include a loop in some way, be it as a boilerplate or *behind the scenes*...