# text from a file turned into a variable?

Tags: c++, text, copy

If I made a program that stores strings on a text file using the "list"-function(#include ), and then I want to copy all of the text from that file and call it something(so I can tell the program to type in all of the text I copied somewhere by using that one variable to refer to the text), do I use a string,double,int or what do I declare that chunk of text as?

I'm making the program using c++ in a simple console application.

### Easier explanation for PoweRoy:

I have a text in a .txt file,I want to copy everything in it and then all this that I just copied, I want to call it "int text" or "string text" or whatever.But I don't know which one of those "int","string","double" etc. to use.

Comment: What the hell do you mean? Can you rephrase?

Comment: It sounds a bit scary to me, writing a program without knowing the basic types of the language.

Comment: it is,I'm no good at c++ at all but I have to learn somehow if the teacher won't help me.
I'm good at javascript though. X)

Comment: The accepted answer below is excellent from a learning perspective, but for future reference, here is another question about ways to pull the whole content of a file into a single string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring/2602060#2602060

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To take some pity on you, this is about the simplest C++ program that reads a file into memory and then does something with it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream  input( "foo.txt" );
    if ( ! input.is_open() ) {
        cerr << "could not open input file" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    vector <string> lines;
    string line;
    while( getline( input, line ) ) {
        lines.push_back( line );
    }

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ ) {
        cout << (i+1) << ": " << lines[i] << "\n"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: @extraneon Never, ever remove the error handling - doing so will make life more complicated, not simpler.

Comment: Most of this is completely extraneous.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, you are talking about the concept of [Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) - storing variable values in permanent storage like a file so you can reload them later.  Have a look at that link to broaden your understanding.

Specifically, it sounds like you have arbitrary text in a file and want to refer to it in your program.  In that case, *string* sounds appropriate.  Unless the text in the file is intended to represent one single number, that seems most appropriate.

Note that if you have structured data (like a CSV file or XML file), a more complex data structure (e.g. a class, array of classes, etc) might be a better choice.

Comment: I didn't quite intend to have a single number,since this text will store several strings and on command it will use a function which will save all of the strings on a .txt file as one single text.And it is bigger than just one character/number.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
   // Open stream from file
   std::ifstream ifs("foo.txt");

   // Get file contents
   std::string file_contents(
      (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),
      std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()
   );

   // Output string to terminal to see that it works
   std::cout << file_contents;
}
```