# What are the differences between streampos and pos_type, streamoff and off_type?

Tags: c++

What are the differences between `streampos` and `pos_type`, `streamoff` and `off_type`, except they are defined differently. What should I use with the `basic_stream<>::seek`'s functions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`std::basic_istream` and `std::basic_ostream` both take two template types, `CharT` and `Traits`. Given a class A that is derived from one of the basic-streams, the `Traits` data type can be retrieved as

```
A::traits_type
```

According to §21.2 of the C++ standard, this data type must provide the following member types:

```
char_type // must be identical to CharT of the basic-stream
off_type
pos_type
```

(and some further data types irrelevant to the present question). Given the [way the `std::basic_istream<>::seekg()` method is defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg), the intended meaning of `off_type` and `pos_type` is:

- `pos_type` is used for absolute positions in the stream
- `off_type` is used for relative positions

So if you want to use the absolute version of `seekg()`, the data type you should declare is `A::pos_type` (which is the same as `A::traits_type::pos_type`). For the relative version it is `A::off_type`.

**Regarding `std::streampos` and `std::streamoff`:** These are defined, too, by the standard as the data types that are used for the *default* version of the `traits_type`. In other words, if you do not explicitly specify the `Traits` template parameter, the `A::pos_type` will *in fact* be `std::streampos`, and `A::off_type` will *in fact* be `std::streamoff`.

**If you create your own version of `Traits`** and want to use it with standard library templates like `std::basic_istream<>` etc., you must include typedefs for `pos_type` and `off_type` (and a lot of other data types), and ensure they comply with §27.2.2 and §27.3 of the standard.

Comment: +1, Further note — `pos_type` is not a scalar number, it also includes information about the state of the text encoding at that position in the file. Its intended purpose is to *return* to a previously encountered position, whereas `off_type` can go somewhere precomputed.