# what type of cast should I use here?

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
m_file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
int fileSize = (int)(m_file.tellg());
m_file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
m_fileContent.resize(fileSize);
m_file.read(m_fileContent.data(), fileSize);
```

the idea is to read the content of a binary file into a vector. This code is compiled and run well, but I am not sure this line is correct in a c++ environment?

```
 int fileSize = (int)(m_file.tellg());
```

Am I using the correct cast? It is a c style cast and not a c++ one. I tried this cast but it generate compiler error:

```
 int fileSize = reinterpret_cast<int>(m_file.tellg());
```

but I am getting this error:

```
'reinterpret_cast' : cannot convert from 'std::fpos<_Mbstatet>' to 'int'
```

what is the best way to cast value types to each other? Should I use C style cast or C++ style cast?

Comment: You shouldn't be casting here at all.  What if the value returned by 'tellg' cannot fit into an 'int'?

Comment: In general, you'd use `static_cast` for explicit numeric conversions. `reinterpret_cast` works on pointers and references, doing the more dangerous job of pretending they point/refer to different types. But you shouldn't use a cast here at all.

Comment: Relevant: [What are the differences between streampos and pos_type, streamoff and off_type?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10133680/2718186)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be casting at all, but rather (assuming C++11) using `auto`, 
i.e.:

```
auto fileSize = m_file.tellg();
```

It will ensure that you don't use the wrong type and avoid implicit casts that may end up in losing info (like casting from a larger type to a smaller one). Plus you don't have to bother with the actual type (which can be cumbersome to type, and that you may get wrong).

Answer (score 3):

You don't want a cast at all, instead use

```
size_t fileSize = file.tellg();
```

Comment: Or `auto fileSize = ...`

Comment: can I use it to resize() a vector?

Comment: @mans [Documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) says "void resize( size_type count );".

Comment: `size_t` might not be large enough to hold the file offset. Its purpose is to be able to hold the size of any object (in memory). Consider a 32 bits address space; then `size_t` being 32 bits is enough, but we can still imagine having a file larger than 4 GiB. You'd have to ask a 'language lawyer' about the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Before `C++11` I believe the correct thing to do is this:

```
std::fstream::pos_type fileSize = m_file.tellg();
```

If you have `C++11` then you can do this:

```
auto fileSize = m_file.tellg();
```

Comment: Not `streampos`, `std::ifstream::pos_type` (assuming `m_file` is an `ifstream`).

Comment: @Barry Fixed. Interesting. One wonders what `std::streampos` is for..?