# Cleanest (reasonably efficient) way to read an entire file into a std::string using boost and/or stdlib

Tags: c++, boost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read whole ASCII file into C++ std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring)

C#

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(filename);
```

Python

```
contents = open(filename).read()
```

Do we really have nothing so simple and concise like that in C++? The best I've seen is:

```
string slurp(const std::string& filename) {
    ifstream ifs("test.txt", ifstream::in);
    stringstream sstr;
    sstr << ifs.rdbuf();
    return sstr.str();
}
```

Which is shameful in a language that's been around so long, with both boost and the stdlib at one's disposal. Easy things should be easy...

Comment: `std::getline(ifs, contents, '\0')`?