# Get the content of a txt file

Tags: c++, windows, file

I am using the windows API in C++ and I want to get the content of a specific txt file. I contemplate using the `ReadFile` function but I don' t know what I should use in place of `HANDLE` or, in other words, how I should pass as parameter the name of the txt file. What is the best way generally to get the content of a txt file using windows API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read whole ASCII file into C++ std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring)

Comment: Just to be sure, you _are_ aware that C++ has a standard API for files and most of the time you don't need to dig into WinAPI?

Comment: @Kos why should he if WinAPI is the best : )

Comment: The best of what, of Windows APIs? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you must invoke [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ("*Creates or opens a file or I/O device*"). It returns a handle which you subsequently pass to [`ReadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

When you are done, don't forget to call [CloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`CreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), supplying `GENERIC_READ` for the `dwDesiredAccess` argument and `OPEN_EXISTING` for the `dwCreationDisposition` argument, to obtain a `HANDLE` to pass to `ReadFile()`.

Or, simpler, just use [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

...

std::vector<std::sting> lines;
std::ifstream in("input.txt");
if (in.is_open())
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(in, line)) lines.push_back(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the HANDLE with [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.