# A one-liner to read text file into std::string in c++?

Tags: c++, string, file-io, ifstream, lines-of-code

Is there a one-liner to read the contents of a (not very big) text file into a string?

The shortest I've found:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>

std::ifstream t("file.txt");
std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

(For large files note that it is extremely inefficient solution since it has to reallocate the buffer after each new character it reads from the stream.)

credit: @Tyler McHenry [Read whole ASCII file into C++ std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring)

Comment: You're asking for a one-liner, then you're asking for the shortest. Which one do you want?

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the practical use for this? Do they deduct a fee from your salary for each line of code you type?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `tourists`.

Comment: @PeterWood: +1 for that comment, I was wondering about it as well :)

Comment: tourists: People looking for the same answer in the far future.

Comment: Write a function to do that, no matter how huge that function would be, But you can call it in one line ;)

Comment: This question helped me

Answer (score 8):

You can do it in a single statement:

```
std::string str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::ifstream("file.txt").rdbuf()), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Whether that's a one-liner depends how big your monitor is...

Answer (score 3):

> *please note that it is not suitable for large files*

Instead of *"being not suitable for large files"* I would rather say that it is ***extremely inefficient*** solution since it has to repeatedly reallocate the buffer as new characters are being read from the stream.

Also note that number of lines of your code is in this case one of the metrics that you should pay least attention to. Once you have [`ifstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) object (name of which should be more meaningful than `t`),
you should check its state, whether it [`is_open()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/is_open/) and much more reasonable way of reading from it seems to be this kind of approach:

```
// obtain the size of the input file stream:
file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
std::streampos fileSize = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

// read the file into the string:
std::string fileData(fileSize);
file.read(&fileData[0], fileSize);
```

*"Less lines of code"* doesn't always mean *"better"*.

Comment: String doesn't expand exponentially?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm actually not sure, I've edited that line. I just have quite unpleasant experiences with reading file contents that way (although I've always used `std::vector` before, not `std::string`)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: In case of exponential expansion, I would be worried about memory requirements of that solution than since sometimes it might lead to almost twice as much memory as needed being allocated.

Comment: The two-iterator constructor of `vector` is constrained to do at most `O(log N)` reallocations (none if the iterator is a ForwardIterator or better, which of course this one isn't), so it must increase exponentially. I don't see that requirement for `basic_string`, though.