# EOF returning blank line or infinite loop

Tags: c++, eof, getline

So I am trying to read from a file named `input_file` till it reaches the end. I've tried using `while (!input_file.eof())` but it goes on for an infinite loop. I looked around on the forum and tried using `while (getline(input_file, line))` but that just returns an empty line. I'm not using both getline() and the >> operator like other questions were.
How do I get around this? Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Main program
void CalfFlac(ifstream& input_file) {
  string text;
  string line;
  while (getline(input_file, line)) {
    text += line;
  }
  cout << text << endl;
}

int main() {
  ifstream input_file;
  input_file.open("calfflac.in");

  CalfFlac(input_file);
}
```

input_file contains a single line `Confucius say: Madam, I'm Adam.` followed by a carriage return.

Thanks for the help!

PS: I'd prefer if the solution remained simple, as this appears to be a pretty simple problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem that you are describing. Even tried it with various line ending combinations like `crlf`, `lf`, `cr`. What platform are you testing this under?

Comment: Did you check that the file opened successfully? `assert(input_file);`

Comment: It is best not to use "assert" to check files, as they can just as easily fail in release mode!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read whole ASCII file into C++ std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring)

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: Make sure you have the right file name! I tried a bogus file name and it printed a blank line as your describe.
I tried your code with a correct file name and it worked for me**

In main add this line:

```
int main() {
  ifstream input_file;
  input_file.open("calfflac.in");

  if(!input_file)
    cout << "File path is wrong!";

  CalfFlac(input_file);
}
```