# C++ Reading in Binary Char Array from stdin

Tags: c++, binary, char, stdin, bit

I am working on a project that works with bits.

Currently we can read in a file name, open it in binary and get a char array from the binary file.
If not file name is given, I have to get the char array from stdin. The input will thus be of variable length.

Is there a way to read the entire stdin into a char array?

Thank you

Comment: Read it into a collection (string, vector, etc.) instead. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2602013/179910

Comment: `std::vector<char> data(std::istream_iterator<char>{std::cin}, std::istream_iterator<char>{});`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::basic_istream::get](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) to get values and put it into an array