# Concerning C++ input and output

Tags: c++, string

I've designed a program that can encrypt 26 English letters.

Here's how I'm handling the input. I'm reading it from a text file and stores it in a string.

```
ifstream L;
string str1;
char ch;
L.open("ToBeCoded.txt");
while(iL.get(ch))
    str1.push_back(ch);
```

However, it's inefficient, if I want to read a different file, I have to change the name in codes to make it work. 
So is there any dynamic way to do so? Like drag the file or type the address of the file during run time?

By the way, do you have a better way to read txt to string? This one 'seems' slow.

Comment: Command line parameters for filename? How many characters do you want to read into your string?

Comment: You can pass the file name as a command line argument.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring

Comment: Two questions in one, too broad.

Answer (score 1):

you can use istream getline instead

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/

Comment: I think he wants to load entire file into one string.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the `getline` for this kind of problem.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/?kw=getline
getline is an ifstream function that will get the string user efficiently.

If you wanted to get the whole string file, just go to the link that Neil Kirk posted:
[Read whole ASCII file into C++ std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring)
it explains exactly how to do that.

Comment: I think he wants to load entire file into one string.

Comment: @NeilKirk I added that. The best reference I could get was yours, hope you don't mind.

Comment: yep, one string is more than enough to store an essay. thx guys

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows you can use DragAcceptFiles and WM_DROPFILES messages. More details here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776406(VS.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774303(VS.85).aspx