# How to read multiple lines in c++

Tags: c++, string

I want to read many lines in one go in c++.I know about getline() method but it reads one line completely.Here is something what i want to do.Reading this whole thing in one go

```
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
```

**P.S:-** when i use getline() method it only reads first line and string length i get is 50 but i want this 1000 character string as whole.Any kind of help?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the number of characters in each line, and you how many lines you want to read, you can just use `fread` or `istream::read` to read a specific number of characters.

Keep in mind the line endings though.

Comment: ok i agree,it will be good for this question.But i was asking as general case

Comment: What is the general case then, if you want to read the complete file into a string you can just use the method described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2602060/1784021

Comment: general case means if i dont know no. of characters in each line

Comment: The answer i linked above will solve that for you. To read a specific number of lines, of unknown length, and get them all in one string. Just use `getline()` and append each line to your final string.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the size of the file N using ifstream methods.

   ```
   myfile.seekg (0, ios::end);
   int N = myfile.tellg();
   ```
2. Read N bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `read(buffer,size)`  when you want to read those 1000 characters string 
in one go.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main () 
{

       char buffer[1000];
       long size;

       ifstream infile ("numbers.txt",ifstream::binary);

       // get size of file
       infile.seekg(0,ifstream::end);
       size=infile.tellg();
       infile.seekg(0);

       //reset buffer to ' '
       memset(buffer,32,sizeof(buffer ));

       // read file content into buffer
       infile.read (buffer,size);

       // display buffer
        cout<<buffer<<"\n\n";

       infile.close();    



  cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.get();


  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450


Press any key to continue
```